# Bibliography Style - Order of Appearance

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

I am looking for a bibliography style with the following characteristics:

1. Numbers references in the order they appear in text.
2. Does not strike out repeated authors like (siam.bst).
3. Very plain formatting on titles (i.e. articles, book, journal).
4. Is able to handle a wide variety of reference types (i.e. journals, book chapters, websites, personal communications, etc.).

I have looked around and tried a handful of alternatives without finding one that fits for my purpose, which is a graduate thesis (i.e. a formal document, but without the space constraints of a journal article).

If there are alternative ways to manage this type of request using the `biblatex` that'd be fine too.

Comment: It's not clear what 3 and 4 are asking for. 1 and 2 should be achievable with a wide variety of styles.

Comment: Is the Science style roughly what you are after?  It's pretty lean - maybe that is what you mean by "Very plain formatting".  Cf. [the example](http://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/contribinfo/prep/res/refs.xhtml#examples); though #2 doesn't make much sense for numbered citations.  Do look at [How to cite chapter in book](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-cite-chapter-in-book) - this qn is relevant to #4.

Comment: @Seamus - I know that 3. and 4. are kinda nebulous. I was hoping to get some best practices from someone who might have had a similar usecase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Seamus has said, there are a lot of styles that cover more or less all of this. I'd probably start with the [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) style `numeric-comp`, which seems to cover what you want. Perhaps you might try that and then ask specific questions on aspects of the formatting which you wish to adjust.

To get you started, a simple example using a couple of references from my own database:

```
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@ARTICLE{Rauchfuss2008,
  author = {Barton, Bryan E. and Olsen, Matthew T. and Rauchfuss, Thomas B.},
  title = {Aza- and Oxadithiolates Are Probable Proton Relays in Functional
    Models for the [FeFe]-Hydrogenases},
  journaltitle = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year = {2008},
  volume = {130},
  pages = {16834-16835},
  number = {50},
  doi = {10.1021/ja8057666},
}

@BOOK{Clegg1998,
  title = {Crystal Structure Determination},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  year = {1998},
  author = {Clegg, William},
  isbn = {978-0-19-855901-6},
  location = {Oxford, U.K.},
}    
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{example}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `filecontents` stuff here is simply to generate a `.bib` file, and I've used `\nocite{*}` to include all references rather than selected citations.

Comment: Thanks - how would I go about using the `biblatex` package  to do this as I'm not familiar.  Thanks.

Comment: @dtlussier: I've added a short example to get you started.

Comment: @dtlussier this question might have useful answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/215

Comment: Thanks - I think `biblatex` is going to be a great solution for me.  Thanks for helping me along with it.

Answer (score 3):

The previous posted examples work.. HOWEVER, by default the bibliography will be sorted by name and numbers will be assigned accordingly, which means that if your first three citations start with the letters C,A,B they will be assigned number 3,1,2.. and that is not what you. You can solve this by adding the `sorting = none` to your preamble. I think you also have  to define the style of citation and bibliography separately in this case, so your preamble could look something like this:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle= nature, citestyle=numeric-comp, sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

Comment: You're right about `sorting=none`. However, this option should also work together with the option `style=numeric-comp`.