# Sorting references in revtex4-1 by order of appearance?

Tags: bibtex, revtex

When preparing an article using the `revtex4-1` LaTeX package, how can I ensure that the references appear in the order that they appear in the text of the document? I've seen answers like [Bibliography Style - Order of Appearance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/bibliography-style-order-of-appearance), but `revtex4-1` bakes in a lot of other BibTeX packages, such as `natbib`, and so I would like to avoid compatibility problems posed by depending on `biblatex` if that is at all possible. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that using `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` should give you what you want.

Comment: Which revtex journal style are you using (ie, `prl`, `pra`, etc)? This should just work, without any special actions from you. You need to run latex, bibtex, latex, latex for a changed order of citations to propagate through the .aux, .bib, .aux (again) files.

Comment: @egreg some versions of revtex4-1 have problems with `\bibliographystyle{}` (should be fixed with the latest patch, though). But it shouldnt be necessary anyway.

Comment: @egreg, @Lev Bishop: It seems that using `unsrtnat` did the trick, so I guess I'm using a late enough version of `revtex4-1` to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The style to use is `unsrtnat`, provided by the **natbib** bundle:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

Comment: This orders the citations correctly but makes the bibliography style very long (full author names, etc.) in revtex4-1 using rmp format.