# How to cite a chapter in a book (update)?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, typography

This is a follow-up question to [How to cite chapter in book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-cite-chapter-in-book)

I like the accepted solution there which basically states that one should use:

> •Boolos, G., 1971/1998. 'The iterative conception of set'. In R.C. Jeffrey (ed.), Logic, Logic, and Logic, Harvard U. Press, pp. 13-29. First published, The Journal of Philosophy, 68:215-232.

I am very happy with this solution as long as ordinary typewriter or handwriting is used. However, when we compile this source then the two opening single quotation marks look weird. To my naive eyes changing the opening quotation mark to `, like

> •Boolos, G., 1971/1998. `The iterative conception of set'. In R.C. Jeffrey (ed.), Logic, Logic, and Logic, Harvard U. Press, pp. 13-29. First published, The Journal of Philosophy, 68:215-232.

would result in a more pleasant outcome after compilation. Is it typographically wrong to use the latter version?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the form of the quotes (straight or dumb quotes) in the posting you're quoting from is just an oversight. One should certainly not use dumb quotes; use back quotes to start the string and ordinary quotes to close the string. In general, this is something that should be handled by the bibliography style you employ; you should worry about the contents of the bibliographic fields, and let BibTeX (or biblatex) handle the typesetting details.

Comment: If this is the best we can come up with, then perhaps a comment should be added to the initial question, and this one should be closed. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I vote to close as off-topic as the question is about changing the visual appearance of a simple example that was not related to a special bst-style. Could just as well be off-topic.