# Inbook the booktitle does not appear in Latex

Tags: cross-referencing, ieeetran

I want to reference a book chapter with IEEETran format. However the booktitle does not appear. The bib file is

```
@Inbook{Lai10,
author="Lai, Lifeng and Gamal, Hesham El and Poor, H. Vincent",
title="Message Authentication: Information Theoretic Bounds",
bookTitle="Securing Wireless Communications at the Physical Layer",
year="2010",
publisher="Springer US",
address="Boston, MA",
pages="335--353",
isbn="978-1-4419-1385-2",
}
```

and the result is like

[image]

Do you know how to add the booktitle to the reference?
Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK, it's `booktitle`, not `bookTitle`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please show us a minimal working example showing your problem, something we can just copy-paste and run.  But many thanks for providing your BibTeX code!

Comment: @naphaneal The capitalisation of field names and entry types in the `.bib` files do not matter.

Answer (score 5):

The answer I found in another page (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2568/203601)
Don't use @inbook ever for anything. Use one of the following, depending on the situation:

@book and \cite[Chapter~5]{foo} for a monograph.

@incollection for a book in which each chapter has a different author. Then the relevant fields are booktitle= and title=; this is similar to @inproceedings.

Comment: This is probably more or less true for many BibTeX styles (which often don't even know a type `@inbook` and have to fall back to `@misc`), but it is not quite true for `biblatex`: With `biblatex` you can use `@inbook` if need be (but one should use it right and only use it if the whole book was written by the same set of authors). But even with `biblatex` it is often the case that `@book` or `@incollection` are the better or more conventional choices.