# Cite InBook with booktitle and coauthors

Tags: bibtex, citing

I use the package `[numbers]{natbib}` and my bibliography style is `unsrtnat`.

I want to cite this chapter of a book: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-05328-7_2#citeas.

The relevant chapter is only written by one author, but I would like to cite it with additional info containing the `booktitle` and the editors that published the book since it is also listed as such on the website.

I wrote all that information into my .bib file (I listed the coauthors as editors / I don't know what option should be used here); it looks like this:

```
@InBook{DecoZeh,
  author    = {Zeh, H.~D.},
  title     = {Basic Concepts and Their Interpretation},
  chapter   = {2},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
  year      = {2003},
  editor    = {Blanchard, P. and Giulini, D. and Joos, E. and Kiefer, C. and Stamatescu, I.~O.},
  booktitle = {Decoherence and the Appearance of a Classical World in Quantum Theory}
}
```

But booktitle and additional authors don't appear in the compiled pdf.

It appears this is intended as such because booktitle and coauthors / editor fields are not included in the "Full template for a chapter or section in a book with authors" on https://www.bibtex.com/t/template-inbook/

Is it customary to just not name the book that the chapter I'm referencing is taken from?

Or why bibtextype / which fields should I use to have the information displayed as like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2518/204015.
I'm not hellbent on naming the full book and others authors, I just want to go with what is customary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@inbook` is not the appropriate entry type for this entry. I suggest you switch to `@incollection`.

[image]

Observe that H. Dieter Zeh is now listed both as an `author` (of chapter 2) and as an `editor`. Observe that I've also backfilled information for the `edition` and `pages` fields.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@incollection{DecoZeh, 
    author    = {Zeh, H. Dieter}, 
    title     = {Basic Concepts and Their Interpretation}, 
    chapter   = {2}, 
    pages     = {7--40},
    edition   = {2nd},
    publisher = {Springer Verlag}, 
    year      = {2003}, 
    editor    = {Erich Joos and H. Dieter Zeh and Claus Kiefer 
                 and Domenico Giulini and Joachim Kupsch 
                 and Ion-Olimpiu Stamatescu}, 
    booktitle = {Decoherence and the Appearance of a 
                 Classical World in Quantum Theory} 
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{DecoZeh}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```