# Reference an Organization on Bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I have a quick question on how to reference organizations that contain more than one word.

For example, I am using this syntax,

```
@misc{Directive2010,
address = {Brussels},
author = {European Parliament and Council of the European Union},
keywords = {Manual,fix},
mendeley-tags = {Manual,fix},
number = {4},
pages = {1--12},
publisher = {European Parliament},
title = {{Directive 2010/30/EU}},
year = {2010}
}
```

The output I get in the text is:
(Parliament and of the European Union, 2010)

and I want it to show as:
(European Parliament and Council of the European Union, 2010)

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want BibTeX to treat something as a single token, you will want to enclose it in braces (*i.e.*, `{}`). So you will want to write:

```
@misc{Directive2010,
address = {Brussels},
author = {{European Parliament and Council of the European Union}},
keywords = {Manual,fix},
mendeley-tags = {Manual,fix},
number = {4},
pages = {1--12},
publisher = {European Parliament},
title = {{Directive 2010/30/EU}},
year = {2010}
}
```

BibTeX treats any occurrence of "and" in the `author` field as a delimiter that separates authors unless you enclose it in braces, like the above code does.

Comment: appendix to the answer: BibTex also treats the first word in general and after every `and` as a forename. The output inside the TOC would be `Parliament, E. and of the European Union, C.` without use of `{...}`

Comment: @Ben That's not always true. Depending on how you enter names, the first word and all first words after the delimiter `and` could be treated as either the "von" part of a name or the surname (*e.g.*, `Smith, Mary and van Beethoven, Ludwig`). See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574/32888) to [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/32888) for the different ways to enter names.

Comment: Oh... you are right. But since there isn't a comma in this case, BibTex does as I told.