# References with italicised author recognised as starting with a with a letter t

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have a reference where the author is not a person, but rather a group, and the first word is in italics, e.g. "*Drosophila* working group". In my reference list, this seems to be recognised as starting with T, rather than D (presumably because it is written as author={\textit{Drosphila} Working Group}). Please see the example below. Can someone advise how I can fix this?
Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
Cite these papers \citep{test1,test2}.
\bibliographystyle{besjournals.bst}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
\end{document}
```

%The refs.bib contains the following

```
@article{test1,
  title={{The genome of Drosophila melanogaster}},
  author={\textit{Drosphila} Working Group}, 
  journal={Plos Biology},
  volume={487},
  number={7405},
  pages={94},
  year={2012},
}

@article{test2,
  title={{Metabarcoding vs. morphological identification to assess diatom diversity in environmental studies}},
  author={Rastas, Oli},
  journal={Measuring Arthropod Biodiversity},
  volume={33},
  number={23},
  pages={3726--3732},
  year={2017},
}
```

Comment: Since the "author" is a group/institution anyway, try adding an extra pair of braces around the entire name. `author={{\textit{Drosphila} Working Group}}` See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129123

Comment: Thank you! As far as I can see, this has fixed it without resorting to the slightly longer solution posted by @Werner. Nonetheless, both answers are of course much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it could be a special case that needs some special hacking. :-|

Following the discussion about sorting and possible workarounds within [Taming the BeaST](//texdoc.net/pkg/beast) (section **10 The title field**, p 22), there is mention of the two processes involved with dealing with each entry - `sort.key$` and `purify$`. The latter removes certain content to aid `sort.key$` in containing only alphanumeric characters. A sneaky way around this is to place a no-op that matches the sorting string at the start of your sorting field; in your case I defined

```
\let\Drosphila\relax
```

and placed it like this:

```
@article{test1,
  title={{The genome of Drosophila melanogaster}},
  author={{\Drosphila\textit{Drosphila} Working Group}}, 
  journal={Plos Biology},
  volume={487},
  number={7405},
  pages={94},
  year={2012}
}
```

Since it's set to `\relax`, it won't expand to anything within the text, but `Drosphila` (and other characters) is used as the `sort.key$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\let\Drosphila\relax % Defined for appropriate sorting

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{refs.bib}
@article{test1,
  title={{The genome of Drosophila melanogaster}},
  author={{\Drosphila\textit{Drosphila} Working Group}}, 
  journal={Plos Biology},
  volume={487},
  number={7405},
  pages={94},
  year={2012}
}

@article{test2,
  title={{Metabarcoding vs. morphological identification to assess diatom diversity in environmental studies}},
  author={Rastas, Oli},
  journal={Measuring Arthropod Biodiversity},
  volume={33},
  number={23},
  pages={3726--3732},
  year={2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Cite these papers \citep{test1,test2}.

\bibliographystyle{besjournals}

\bibliography{refs.bib}

\end{document}
```