# Only last name for natbib citep

Tags: citing, natbib, drop-cap

I want my citations to be shown as (LastName, year) instead of (LastName Initials, year).
I am using the natbib package, with setting 'authoryear'.

*Below a minimilistic example:*

My .tex file:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}

Document body text with citations \\
\citep{Bertram91} \\
\citep{Bertram06} \\ 

\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{myreferences}

\end{document}
```

And my .bib file:

```
@article{Bertram91,
        author = "Bertram C.D., Raymond C.J.",
        title = "Measurements of wave speed...",
        journal = "Med. and Biol. Eng. and Comput.",
        volume = "29",
        year = "1991",
        pages = "493--500",
}

@article{Bertram06,
        author = "Bertram C.D., Tscherry J.",
        title = "The onset of flow-rate...",
        journal = "Journal of Fluids and Structures",
        volume = "22",
        year = "2006",
        pages = "1029--1045",
}
```

This gives the output:

[image]

I do NOT want the initials in the citation.

Comment: No need to thank or sign in your question. The nice MWE should make it easy for you to get help.

Comment: Your input file seems not exactly to conform to the BibTeX syntax. The name format is `Last, First and Last, First`, so you need `author = "Bertram, C. D. and Raymond, C. J."` and `author = "Bertram, C. D. and Tscherry, J."` (or `author = " C. D. Bertram and C. J. Raymond"` and `author = "C. D. Bertram and J. Tscherry"`).

Comment: Wow that did change the citations in a major way :) It is now showing correctly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @moewe No, it's a completely different problem.

Comment: @egreg Blast! Of course, I must have been still a bit drowsy. Sorry about that. I assume [How should I type author names in a bib file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864) is much more appropriate, then. I git too entangled in the initials block, though that needed change as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to your input (and to BibTeX rules), the paper `Bertram91` has just *one* author, whose family name is “Bertram C.D.” and given name is “ Raymond C.J.”.

An author should be given in the form

```
Family, Given
```

(also `Given Family` can be used, but it's better to stick with a scheme; `Given` can of course be just the initials).

Authors *must* be separated by `and`. So the correct syntax for your paper is

```
@article{Bertram91,
    author = "Bertram, C.D. and Raymond, C.J.",
    [...]
```

Comment: Would you mind if I changed the initials block as in the question I initially voted this to be a duplicate of?