# Some fields don't show up or are missing formatting in the bibliography even though I have entries for them

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am trying to add several types of bibliography entries using the "standard" BibLaTeX options in LaTex editor. For example:

I have a multi-author book, so I enter each name in the Author field with commas, but they erratically show up in the entry.

The date or year entry often does not show up.

I have a court case that I used an "article" format for, with creative use of some of the optional fields to get the full citation, but not all the fields show up, so I have to jam everything into the title.

Is there a way to make LaTeX interpret the bibliography file more "literally", and not try to interpret each entry?

Here are some actual entries in my .bib file that are not fully displaying (missing date field):

```
@book{ELA, 
  author = {Tod I. Zuckerman Thomas J. Bois II Thomas M.Johnson}, 
  title = {Envrionmental Liability Allocation: Law and Practice}, 
  date = {2011}, chapter = {3}
}

@book{Rodricks, 
  author = {Joseph V. Rodricks}, 
  title = {Calculated Risks}, 
  date = {2007}, 
  edition = {2nd}, 
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press}
}
```

Comment: As this is an *unexpected* result, it would be best if you provided a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) that demonstrates the problem.  Legal citations can be incredibly difficult to implement properly, so it may be an issue with the legal style you are using or trying to use.  It is hard to say.  And are you really using the *package* [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)?  (I'm not trolling, but 'using the "standard" BibLaTeX options in LaTeX editor' sounds like you might be using traditional BibTeX.)

Answer (score 4):

See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574/21344) for details on entering multiple authors.

To display the information you require, search for BibTeX styles (good survey [here](http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html)) that use the fields desired. You may find that styles specific to your area of study include the fields you are expecting.

Not all styles use information from every field. For cases where the majority of the bibliography is as desired, but a few references are missing information, you can use the `note` field, which is always appended to the bib entry. But this should be used sparingly.

Comment: I've never seen one which didn't at least use the year from the date, though!

Answer (score 1):

Please post a Minimum Working Example which can be compiled to demonstrate your problem. I cannot reproduce it using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{ELA,
  author = {Tod I. Zuckerman Thomas J. Bois II Thomas M.Johnson},
  title = {Envrionmental Liability Allocation: Law and Practice},
  date = {2011}, chapter = {3}
}

@book{Rodricks,
  author = {Joseph V. Rodricks},
  title = {Calculated Risks},
  date = {2007},
  edition = {2nd},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\Cite{Rodricks}

\Cite{ELA}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

While I doubt this is what you want, I don't see information disappearing:

[image: references and bibliography not losing information]

As Paul Gessler says, you need to enter the authors correctly. For example:

```
author = {Zuckerman, Tod I. and Bois, II, Thomas J. and Johnson, Thomas M.},
```

You could use

```
author = {Tod I. Zuckerman and Bois, II, Thomas J. and Thomas M. Johnson},
```

However, I generally find it easier to always use the `Last, First Middle` format since it is sometimes needed e.g. with suffixes such as `II`.

I don't know if there is a rule about this, but it is at least conventional to put each field on a new line. So I would use, for example:

```
  date = {2011},
  chapter = {3}
```

rather than putting them on a single line. It is also better to write

```
edition = {2},
```

and allow the style you choose to decide how best to format it. This helps with consistency (p. 16).