# Referencing a "two-part" surname

Tags: bibtex

Currently my bibtex entry is this:

```
@Article{CW12,
author  = "Neil Rankin and Vivian Sch{\"o}er and Christian Sebastiao and Corne Van Walbeek",
title   = "Predictors of academic performance: {N}ational {S}enior {C}ertificate versus {N}ational Benchmark {T}est",
year    = "2012",
journal = "South African Journal of Higher Education",
volume  = "26",
number  = "3",
pages   = "564-585"
}
```

Everything is fine, except that in the reference list, Corne Van Walbeek is referenced as Walbeek, C. V. Obviously this is incorrect and I would like the reference to be Van Walbeek, C. I am using the Natbib package with the 'apalike' style.

Comment: it's usually recommended to enter all names in the form "last name, first".  this would be "Rankin, Neil and ... and Van Walbeek, Corne" for your entry.  then it's clear what is last name, and what first.

Comment: You can also do either `{Van Walbeek}` or `\uppercase{v}an Walbeek` depending on how you want the `Van` part treated.

Comment: To elaborate on previous comments, `Corne van Walbeek` (lowercase v) would be correctly detected by BibTeX ([details](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574/21344)), but if you need the capitalization, use the aforementioned methods.

Comment: Thanks Barbara and Nicola! Paul: Yes, I double-checked his name and it seems he uses "Van" rather than "van".

Comment: @barbarabeeton An answer?

Answer (score 3):

it's usually recommended to enter all names in the form "last name, first".
this makes it clear to bibtex which part is which.

for your entry, this would be

```
author  = "Rankin, Neil and Sch{\"o}er, Vivian and Sebastiao, Christian and Van Walbeek" Corne",
```

if you insist on entering names in "hatural" order, you can tie the two-part
last name together as `{Van Walbeek}`, as suggested by nicola talbot.