# The word "Print" appears after every source using \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, mla-style, biblatex-mla

I am using the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=mla]{biblatex}

\nocite{*}

...


\begin{document}

text... \footcite{source}

\printbibliography[heading=none]


\end{document}
```

Why is there's an extra "print" after each source?

[image]

Comment: `electronic`, `media` or `print`

Comment: try and set `showmedium=false` in the options.

Comment: Note that you somewhat garbled Mr. Davis's name; it should be `author  = {Davis, III, Roy B. and Sylvia Õunpuu and Dennis Tyburski and James R. Gage},` and not `author  = {Roy B. Davis III and Sylvia Õunpuu and Dennis Tyburski and James R. Gage},` in the `.bib` file. (See [How should I type author names in a bib file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The MLA style guide requires the medium of the publication to be shown (see, for example [MLA Citation Style  | Cornell University Library](https://www.library.cornell.edu/resrch/citmanage/mla)).

`biblatex-mla` tries to satisfy this requirement  by printing the medium of publication at the end of every bibliography entry (via the macro `publimedium`). If the `howpublished` field contains any information, that information is printed. If `howpublished` is not given,  the default option `guessmedium` is active, `biblatex-mla` will guess the medium of publication.

To stop `biblatex-mla` from printing this information, just use the option `showmedium=false`, so your call to `biblatex` becomes

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=mla,showmedium=false]{biblatex}
```

---

Your example reveals another problem though, "print" is printed in bold, to warn you that `[the] Bibliography string 'print' [is] undefined` (see log file).

`biblatex-mla` does not provide a Swedish language file, so some bibstrings are missing, to get this particular one back, try

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{swedish}{%
  print = {whatever \enquote{print} means in Swedish},
}
```

Now, "**print**" is replaced by "whatever 'print' means in Swedish".