# How to suppress 'Print' in \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-mla

I am trying to cite a book using a biblatex-generated bibliography. By default, `Print.` is appended to the end of the bibliogrpahy entry, as this is the default value of the `howpublished` field.
I want to remove this, but I can't seem to keep it out. I can replace it with text by changing `howpublished` but even whitespace doesn't work. Is there a solution here?

Comment: Could you post a compilable code? T=As far as I know, the field `howpubished`, is always an optional field, so perhaps the simplest would be to not use it.

Comment: @Bernard Here is a sample entry:
```@book{emerson.poe,
    author = "Ralph Waldo Emerson",
    title = "The Poet"
}```. I don't have the field at all, but biblatex appends 'Print' to the end. My problem with it is that I am not accessing the work through print, but for my bibliography I don't want to list a method of publication at all.

Comment: Perhaps it is there's no year/date (which is mandatory   for @ book)?

Comment: That is a feature of MLA style: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165580/35864. If you don't have to follow MLA rules, I suggest you choose a different (standard) style.

Comment: @moewe Aha! And the answer to my question then seems to be `showmedium=false` when calling biblatex. I suppose this can be marked duplicate then.