# Bibliography string 'print' unstranslated

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-mla

I am having trouble with  my bibliography. After each cite/source it writes "print" in the bibliography and I don't know how to remove it or get rid of it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=mla,
]{biblatex} %kildehenvisning \parencite{}, husk selv at skrive årstal.

\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}  % Required for make compact versions of itemize, description, and enumerate.
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}  % Used for having multiple figures side by side, as well as their aligment -- MUST be loaded before the hyperref package !!!
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}    % Required for creating a border around math-theorems



% The standard graphics inclusion package
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Set up how figure and table captions are displayed
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
  font=footnotesize,% set font size to footnotesize
  labelfont=bf % bold label (e.g., Figure 3.2) font
}
% Make the standard latex tables look so much better
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
% Enable the use of frames around, e.g., theorems
% The framed package is used in the example environment
\usepackage{framed}

% Modify how \chapter, \section, etc. look
% The titlesec package is very configureable
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}

% Clear empty pages between chapters
%\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
%\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
%  \clearpage
%  {\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}%
%}
%\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage

% Change the headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}   % Changes the header style.
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Spaces around titles
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{6pt}{15pt}{9pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{5pt}{12pt}{7pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{4pt}{11pt}{6pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{3pt}{10pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{3pt}{8pt}{3pt}

\definecolor{greyshade}{rgb}{0.800,0.800,0.800}
\definecolor{aau}{rgb}{0.2,0.39,0.6}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\TPGrid[40mm,23mm]{100}{100}

% Chapter headings design
\makeatletter
    \def\@makechapterhead#1{{
        \begin{textblock}{27}(74,0)
            \begin{flushright}
                {\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont\bfseries\textcolor{white}{1.}\@chapapp}\;\;\;\\
                \vspace{3pt}
                {\fontsize{85}{85}\selectfont\bfseries\textcolor{greyshade}{\thechapter}}   
            \end{flushright}
        \end{textblock}
        \vspace*{0.7cm}
        \begin{textblock}{68}[0,1](0,13.5)\Huge\bfseries \noindent #1\end{textblock}
        \vspace*{0.25cm}
        \hrule
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
    }}
\makeatother
% Enable arithmetics with length. Useful when
% typesetting the layout.
\usepackage{calc}

\rfoot{Side \thepage \hspace{1pt} af \pageref{LastPage}}
\usepackage{lastpage}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{
%   pdfpagelabels=true,
%   plainpages=false,
%   pdfauthor={Author(s)},
%pdftitle={Title},%
%   pdfsubject={Subject},%
%   bookmarksnumbered=true,%
%   colorlinks=false,%
%   citecolor=black,%
%   filecolor=black,%
%   linkcolor=black,% you should probably change this to black before printing
%   urlcolor=black,%
%   pdfstartview=FitH%
%}



\newcommand{\blankpage} {
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \mbox{}
    \newpage
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\newcommand{\quotePlain}[1] {
    \begin{quotation}
        " \em #1 "
    \end{quotation}
}
\newcommand{\quoteWithCite}[2] {
    \begin{quotation}
        " \em #1 "\normalfont{\cite{#2}}
    \end{quotation}
}


\usepackage{csquotes}

%links
\usepackage{hyperref} %url
  \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0},
          linkcolor=red
          }
```

Comment: Did you try another bib style (other than `style=mla`), e.g. `style=ieee` and then the problem of extra "print" still persist? I also see an unnecessary comma at your style definition `style=mla,`

Comment: You may also reduce the size of  your posted example that shows the problem to a MWE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Rewrite your biblatex command as follows:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=mla, showmedium=false]{biblatex} % kildehenvisning \parencite{}, husk selv at skrive årstal.
```

**The Problem:**

As the Questioner did not provide a MWE, so here is one which reproduce the mentioned problem of the extra "print" word in bibliography:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=mla]{biblatex} % or backend=biber
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%
\begin{document}
%
%
\chapter{Reference and Citation} \label{ch:reference}
%
\section{Introduction} \label{sec:intro}
In order to cite one reference, you can use cite command like this \cite{Doe_2020}. You can also cite two references like this \cite{Doe_2020,Tenis_2000}.
%
\printbibliography
%
\end{document}
```

Which produce an output with the extra "print" as

[image]

**Solution:**

When using the `mla` style, the medium of the publication should be specified, if not, then the default "Print" will be shown next to each bib entry in the bibliography as happened with the questioner.

The solution is just adding the `biblatex` option `showmedium=false`. Using the same MWE code above after adding that option like this

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=mla, showmedium=false]{biblatex}
```

will remove that extra print as follows:

[image]

**Language translation:**

If your problem is additionally related to language translation format, as your question title suggests, and guessing it's Danish (judging from your comments), then you may use `babel` package with danish option by adding the followin line in the preamble

```
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
```

By which you will obtain the following output without `showmedium=false`

[image]

and with using `showmedium=false`

[image]

Comment: @moewe Thanks for inspiration https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165583/91556

Comment: Thank you very much!