# How to correctly display and separate the author names in a bibliographic entry?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

How to correctly display and to separate among the BibLaTeX's author's names?

Code:

```
@book{atl1,
    label     = {SELLS},
    author    = {Cristopher TAVARES, Kirk FERTITTA, Brent RECTOR, Chris SELLS},
    title     = {ATL Internals},
    subtitle  = {Working with ATL 8},
    edition   = {2},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
    date      = {2006-07-15},
    pages     = {888}
    }
```

Output:

[image]

In this case I'm trying to display this as `Cristopher TAVARES, Kirk FERTITTA, Brent RECTOR and Chris SELLS` before `ATL Internals...`.

How do I to deal with this, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Two things about your `author` field. (1) Names should be separated by the `and` keyword (`author = {Jane Smith and John Doe}`). (2) You should not capitalise the last names; if you want the last names to appear capitalised in the document, use `\newcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}` or - if you insist - `\newcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}`. In your MWE the correct `author` field would be `author = {Cristopher Tavares and Kirk Fertitta and Brent Rector and Chris Sells},`.

Comment: If the above does not give you the expected output, we really need to see a full proper MWE.

Comment: Sorry, the `\newcommand*`s in my first comment above should have been `\renewcommand*`s, the first redefinition should have read `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}` (the second redefinition needs to be modified analogically).

Comment: Another thing: I assume "888" is the number of pages of that book, not a specific page of that book you cite (why would one add the specific page to the bibliography?). In that case `pagetotal` is the field you are looking for, not `pages`. `pages` is for "[o]ne or more page numbers or page ranges. If the work is published as part of another one, such as an article in a journal or a collection, this field holds the relevant page range in that other work. It may also be used to limit the reference to a specific part of a work.", while `pagetotal` holds "[t]he total number of pages of the work."

Comment: @moewe, thank you very much! That've worked! You may want to make an answer to mark this as resolved?

Comment: Better format for the author names in the `bib` file is Last, First: `author = {Smith, Jane and Doe, John}`, particularly when names can have "von" parts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `author` field is not properly formatted for BibTeX/`biblatex`.

According to [Tame the BeaST](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf), §11 *The `author` field*, p. 23:

1. Names are separated by the keyword `and`: `author = {Smith, Jane and Doe, John}`
2. Names must be given in one of three formats

   1. "First von Last": `author = {Johann Wolfgang von Goethe}`,
   2. "von Last, First": `author = {von Goethe, Johann Wolfgang}`, or
   3. "von Last, Jr, First": `author = {von Goethe, Johann Wolfgang}`.

See also [How should I type author names in a `.bib` file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864) and [Norman Walsh's help on BibTeX names](http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/bibtx-23.html).

You should furthermore not apply any formatting to the names - except for proper capitalisation of names, of course.
Do not write `author = {John SMITH}`, but `author = {John Smith}`.

Formatting of last names will be taken care of by the bibliography style you use.
In `biblatex` that is as easy as `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}` (or - if you absolutely insist on using all caps for the last name <sub>don't do it!</sub> - `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}`).

All in all, your `author` field should read

```
author = {Tavares, Cristopher and Fertitta, Kirk and Rector, Brent and Sells, Chris}
```

Of course

```
author = {Cristopher Tavares and Kirk Fertitta and Brent Rector and Chris Sells}
```

is equally fine (and maybe slightly more convenient).