# Automatically reorder author names in bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I have a bibtex file with over 1000 publications in it and I would like to homogeneize this database.

For this purpose I used bibclean which worked pretty well. However bibclean give me names in the form "firstnames lastname and firstnames lastname". Do you know of a way to get all the references with the form "lastname, firstname and lastname, firstname" ?

This is to avoid misreading of people having two lastnames or von / jr. initials.

I read this:
[How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557/how-should-i-type-author-names-in-a-bib-file)

which helped me to better understand my problem but did not advise any specific tool.

Any idea ?

Comment: Thanks for your time. To be honest I do not really know. After a check I found various ways:
D. McG. LastName (with McG. being a first hence this is not a problem)
A. Lastname1 Lastname2 (which as I understand will be a problem).

So I should for instance use brackets to ensure that the lastnames stay together (if I understood correctly). But then the question of the tool is remaining.

Comment: `biber --tool` and `bibtool` are two possibilities, but as I far as I can see neither has a standard rule for normalising the author field, you would have to build one yourself.