# Finding out automatically generated sortkeys

Tags: biblatex, biber, chicago-style

If I want to manually place an entry in my bibliography at another place I can do so using the `sortkey`. But, to be able to do that I will need to know its neighbours' `sortkey`s or whatever the equivalent internally used by `biblatex`/`biber` is called. Particularly if one has one author writing with different coauthors it seems to be quite a complex sorting algorithm, which I don't understand yet. I will need to either understand the sorting algorithm, or know where I can see the autmatically generated keys via some debug switch or maybe in the `bbl`-file, is that possible? I am using `biblatex-chicago` with `authordate` style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biber` sorting is quite complicated. It doesn't sort using just a key but uses an array of keys defined by the sorting specification. You can't reliably do real multi-field sorting with just one string to compare. You can see the sorting object used for each entry if you run `biber` with `--debug` and then check the `.blg` file for the string:

```
DEBUG - Sorting object for key
```

There you will see a dump of the sorting array. Basically, `biber` compares the first element of the array for each key, then the second etc. and so on, using extra information from the sorting specification about order, when to stop etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a complete answer, but just some observations I made dealing with the problem. I haven't found a place where these keys get displayed. `biblatex` has a `style=debug` package option, but it doesn't display what I'm searching for. For the `biblatex-chicago` package I haven't found a way to display this debug information, I guess it's not implemented there. Anyhow, the biggest problem lies in the name, the `author` or `editor` field, which in most sorting schemes is the first field considered. If one has more than one author they are separated by `and`. Now while we get an output like "Alastname, Afirstname, and Bfirstname Blastname.", we have to assume the string internally taken for the sorting to be "AlastnameAfirstnameBlastnameBfirstname". In the `nyt` sorting scheme next comes the year, then the title.

EDIT: In an earlier version of this answer I was guessing the following:

> One crucial point there is to understand that `author = {lastname, firstname},` is wrong, even though on first sight it seems to work. If one wants the automatic sorting via `biber` to function properly one needs to write `{firstname lastname}`.

But this is not the case. `biber`/`biblatex` obviously can deal with names in reverse order, as the following example shows, particularly the second entry, where it reestablishes the natural order of reverted names:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}


@book { reverseorder1,
author = {Alast, Afirst},
%author = {Afirst Alast},
title = {one author in reverse order},
year = {2015},
}

@book { reverseorder2,
author = {Xlast, Xfirst and Ylast, Yfirst and Zlast, Zfirst},
title = {three authors in reverse order},
year = {2015},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It is interesting to note however that if one does not capitalise the names biber will not know what to do with them and output a warning.

Comment: I would like to see a proof of the claim that `lastname, firstname` and `firstname lastname` produce different results. I always thought they are interpreted exactly the same and in fact in a test I just conducted both forms were treated exactly the same in all aspects in the `.bbl` file.

Comment: Sorting is determined by applying the name format `sortname` to the first field in the order of precedence of the name part of the sorting scheme.

Comment: @moewe Good point about the reverse order of the name in the .bib file, which indeed was more of a claim on my behalf than confirmed knowledge. But I just tested a minimal file with reverse order of name here and I got warnings, due to which the `author` field got omitted from the entry. When I changed the order back to "normal" biber didn't give me a warning and the entry got rendered as expected. Anyway, in my real file in which authors occured in reverse order I didn't get any warnings, also the entries didn't look wrong, just the order of entries was not as expected.

Comment: That is very interesting ... I also got an error about "Couldn't determine Last Name for name "alast, afirst" - ignoring name" when I tried your example. When I, however, decided to capitalise the name (as I imagine most names in the wild are) as "Alast, Afirst" everything went fine. So Biber seems to deal with non-capitalised names differently. (Maybe that is worth a complaint on the [Biber bugtracker](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/), the request might be struck down immediately though, because there are very few (no?) lower-case names.)

Comment: Still I would prefer if you were to tone down your claim that "Lastname, Firstname" is wrong. See [How should I type author names in a bib file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864) for reference, where "von Last, First" is one of the listed formats.

Comment: I would also really like to see a real-life example where the order in the `author` field affected sorting. From everything I have read and experienced so far *it really shouldn't*.

Comment: @moewe I edited my answer again. About real life example, well, I guess biblatex / and biber do everything right, but I was confronted with a few entries where the editor of some sanskrit works has the habit of adding all the people that helped him in preparing his edition to the bibliographical details, nice and humble, but if you have a few entries with name fields such as "A, ed., in collaboration with B and C and with contributions from D, E, F and others" as the author field and then somebody tells you that "they are getting sorted in the wrong way" you start shooting into the dark.

Comment: Note that "A, ed., in collaboration with B and C and with contributions from D, E, F and others" should never be used in the `author` field in `biblatex` (not least because none of them are authors in the technical sense).

Comment: @jon Yes, I guess normally one would put A in the editor field, and then the rest of the people in a note field. Which, using authordate style in biblatex-chicago, would lead to them being printed after the title. Alternatively I could use nameaddon, in which case they are printed after the main editor but in square brackets. Now if you are required to, without making any change to it, put this long string of names at the beginning then what do you do? Anyway, I found a solution with `{{}}`, `sortkey` and `shortauthor` but I also understand that's not how it's meant to be done.

Comment: I wouldn't do any of those things. I would use the appropriate "editor" fields as they are described in `§.2.3.6` of the `biblatex` manual.  I would also consider the sage advice of the `biblatex-chicago` manual, where it points out that just because you *can* put in all conceivable publication information into a `.bib` entry, it doesn't mean you should or must.  The point of a bibliography is not to describe an item *ad nauseam*, but *ad differentiam (notandam)*....

Comment: There even is the `editor(_)type` "collaborator" (there is no "contributor", though). If you are required to mention all people, you could all add them to the `editor` field but without any further formatting just `editor = {Eddi Important and Micheal Inion and Frank O. Otman and Ronald Ighthand}`. In case you have the do mention everyone, the "best" way would obviously be to define a "contributor" and go with `editor = {Eddi Important}, editora = {Micheal Inion}, editoratype = {contributor}, editorb = {Frank O. Otman and Ronald Ighthand}, editorbtype = {collaborator}`.

Comment: Or you could just follow `biblatex-chicago`'s advice that jon quoted above and drop the collaborators as in `editor = {Eddi Importan}`.