# Neither bibliography nor cites printed (biber)

Tags: biblatex, biber

I've had a rough time trying to print a bibliography in a document. I wrote a MWE and found even more issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle,english=american]{csquotes}

\addbibresource{tb.bib}

\begin{document}
I'd like to cite Masere and friends \cite{masere}, as well as Strogatz \cite{strogatz}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the `.bib` file contains the following:

```
@article{masere,
author="J. Masere, D. A. Vasquez, B. F. Edwards, J. W. Wilder, and K. Showalter",
title="Nonaxisymmetric and Axisymmetric Convection in Propagating Reaction-Diffusion Fronts",
journal="J. Phys. Chem.",
volume="98",
number="26",
pages="6505--6508",
year="1994",
doi="http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/j100077a014",
}

@book{strogatz,
title={Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos},
subtitle={With Applications to Physics, Biology, Chemistry, and Engineering},
author={S. H. Strogatz},
isbn={0-201-54344-3},
series={Studies in Nonlinearity},
year={1994},
publisher={Perseus Books},
}
```

After using `pdflatex test.tex` on the command prompt, I get the following:

```
No file test.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'masere' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'strogatz' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 10.

[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\Users\me\Documents\Sandbox\test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

After that, I used `biber test.tex` and got:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.1
INFO - Logfile is 'test.tex.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'test.tex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

I also found this last `ERROR` in my original file, and now I really don't know what to do. I just realized that this question is quite long, and I apologize for that.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try to run the files without extension: "pdflatex test", "biber test", "pdflatex test"

Comment: You need to run `biber test`, not `biber test.tex`. See also [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for a bit more background and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) on how to set up your editor.

Comment: And to think it was so easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the folder where your tex file is. Pdflatex should have created the file `test.bcf` in that folder. (At least, this is what happens on my machine.)

Note that biber is looking for `test.tex.bcf` with *two* extensions. Maybe you need to run `biber test` (instead of  `biber test.tex`) instead.

Comment: As others pointed out, this was the main issue. It's a bit embarassing that the file extension caused me so much trouble, though.

There was one more thing: biber didn't like the `author` entry to have so many commas, which resulted in problems. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Drarp Yes, the name list in your example above is off it should be `{J. Masere and D. A. Vasquez and B. F. Edwards and J. W. Wilder and K. Showalter}` you must separate two authors by `and`, commas are there to delimit the parts of a name, not to separate two authors. See also [How should I type author names in a bib file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864). Biber might be a bit more sensitive to these issues and sometimes throws more prominent warnings than BibTeX does.

Answer (score 0):

If you work bit around, this should work fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[authoryear,numbers,round]{natbib}
\usepackage[autostyle,english=american]{csquotes}


%\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
 I'd like to cite Masere and friends \cite{masere}, as well as Strogatz \cite{strogatz}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Just put the name of the **.bib** file in the same folder or put the path file to the **\bibliography** and it should work fine.

[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Maybe, just maybe - I don't know, I didn't vote on this answer - because it is bending the aim of the question a bit by employing `natbib` instead of `biblatex`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Probably because it switches to `natbib`. Still, thanks for providing an alternative, Slavisa.