# biber and ~ provides an incorrect output

Tags: biblatex, biber

As I usually do, I use `~` when I use abbreviations in bibliographies. To my surprise, when I do this using `biber` it duplicates the initials that are abbreviated. Nevertheless, if I change to `backend=bibtex`, everything works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@inproceedings{Batista:2014b,
  title={Power Prediction prior to Scheduling Combined with Equal Power Allocation for the {OFDMA} {UL}},
  author={Rodrigo L.~Batista and Carlos F.~M.~e~Silva and Jos\'{e} M.~B.~da~Silva~Jr.\@ and Tarcisio F.~Maciel and Francisco R.~P.~Cavalcanti},
    booktitle={European Wireless},
  year=2014,
  address={Barcelona, Spain},
  month=may,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    %backend=bibtex,
    style=ieee,
    ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Batista:2014b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In the MWE above it gives

> R. L. L. Batista, C. F. M. F. M. e Silva, J. M. B. M. B. da Silva Jr.,
>   T. F. F. Maciel, and F. R. P. R. P. Cavalcanti, “Power prediction
>   prior to scheduling combined with equal power allocation for the OFDMA
>   UL,” in European Wireless, Barcelona, Spain, May 2014.

But the correct output should be as below, which is achieved with `backend=bibtex`:

> R. L. Batista, C. F. M. e Silva, J. M. B. da Silva Jr., T. F. Maciel,
>   and F. R. P. Cavalcanti, “Power prediction prior to scheduling
>   combined with equal power allocation for the OFDMA UL,” in European
>   Wireless, Barcelona, Spain, May 2014.

The question is: how can I make `biber` to correctly operate without removing the `~` or alternatively by removing the `~` would I have the correct spacing after each middle `.`?

Comment: I don't think one should enter names with `~`s, it will simply confuse Biber. ([How should I type author names in a bib file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864) doesn't mention ties at all.) With Biber you can modify the spacing after middle initials, what spacing do you want?

Comment: The best input would be `author={Rodrigo L. Batista and e Silva, Carlos F. M. and da Silva, Jr., Jos\'{e} M. B. and Tarcisio F. Maciel and Francisco R. P. Cavalcanti},` I assume (though you might have to check the status of the `e` for `e Silva` is it a *von* part?).

Comment: @moewe's answer is correct - you shouldn't put these in the .bib - biber+biblatex has a set of macros you can change to control name spacing and the slightly idiosyncratic btparpse C library which biber uses to parse names doesn't like attempted formatting in the .bib which is a reasonable sensitivity since formatting is a job for the bibliography style and not the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864) a correct way to give the author names would be

```
author = {Rodrigo L. Batista and e Silva, Carlos F. M. and
          da Silva, Jr., Jos\'{e} M. B. and Tarcisio F. Maciel and 
          Francisco R. P. Cavalcanti},
```

I don't think you should use `~`s to format the names. Apparently BibTeX simply ignores them when decomposing the names (that means the content of the `.bbl` files are the same with and without the `~`s), but Biber chokes.

Seeing that the `~` are no use in BibTeX and startle Biber, I would get rid of them. The spacing between name parts and initials is controlled by `biblatex` as explained in §3.12.4 *Name Parts and Name Spacing*, pp. 119-121, of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

`\bibinitdelim` controls the spacing between initials.

If you don't want to get rid of the `~` in your `.bib` file (you should, though!), we can map them away with Biber's sourcemapping

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{\step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{~}, replace={\ }]}
    \map{\step[fieldsource=editor, match=\regexp{~}, replace={\ }]}
    \map{\step[fieldsource=translator, match=\regexp{~}, replace={\ }]}
  }
}
```

Comment: I asked Paulo about the name of the second author, which is “Carlos Felipe Moreira e Silva”, where the “e” is not like a “von”. He promised to consult official sources, but in all citations I found about him, the “e” is dropped.

Comment: @egreg Oh, thanks for doing the research. If the "e" is not a *von* part and we don't want it treated like one but not like a name initial either, we will have to think of something more creative. (Apparently, a single `e` is treated like a name initial and not just a "word".)

Comment: @moewe @egreg the `e` in the second author should be treated as `Silva, Carlos F. M. e`. It makes no sense to have `e` in the front.

Comment: The answer from Paulo's consultant is “use ‘Moreira e Silva’ even if this can cause confusion”. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24869916#24869916

Comment: @egreg Thanks for following this up. That has the advantage that `Moreira e Silva, Carlos F.` doesn't confuse Biber with respect to the status of the `e`.