# bibtex and biblatex customing in sharelatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, sharelatex, custom-bib

So I have fighting with this problem now two days. Result: nod good...
In the picture is example what I try to do. First ones are made by hand and after "lähteet" is what biblatex is doing. I can't make custom-bib, because I'm using sharelatex.com...

This is what I have done do look like that.

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
style=authoryear-icomp,
bibencoding=ascii
%style=alphabetic
%style=reading
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\addbibresource{luettelo}
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{\printtext[parens]}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{edition}{\printtext[parens]}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\xpatchbibmacro*{in:}{\bibstring{in}}{%
      \setunit{}  
      \printtext%
}{}{}

\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
```

Here is .bib file:

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}

@article{Shabana,
    author    = "Shabana, Ahmed A",
    title     = "Computational Dynamics",
    year      = "2001",
    publisher = "John Wiley & Sons.",
    pages     = "522 s."   
}
@inbook{inbook,
  author       = "Hirsjärvi, S., Remes, P. & Sajavaara, P", 
  title        = "Tutki ja kirjoita",
  chapter      = 8,
  pages        = {201-213},
  publisher    = {The name of the publisher},
  year         = 2005,
  address      = {The address of the publisher},
  edition      = 10,
  note         = {An optional note}
}
```

My question is: is it even possible customize so much in sharelatex? Or is there another library what to use? 
Any of the ready-made styles doesn't fit.

Another question is, can I make latex library to read bib file and print them in right style and right order?

Help needed...

[image: Example style]

Comment: Can you post a full example of what exactly you have so far in your document including a few example `.bib` entries? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) Note that your format for the Einstein article is not appropriate for a bibliography, you are leaving out important information there.

Comment: A `.bib` entry alone is unfortunately not enough to understand your problem in detail. We also need to see the document calling the `.bib` file. It would also be great if you could explain in more detail what output you want. Note that your `.bib` file contains some problems: unescaped `&`s and [wrong name formats](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864) as well as escape sequences in the URL. `url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html"` should be OK.

Comment: Or is there possible to use natbib and thebibliography, where cite is authoryear style? (Einstein,A. 1905)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what exactly you want. Can you show a mock-up of what you want the bibliography and citations to the posted `.bib` entries to look like?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my question or solution:

use:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Enstein(1905]{Ein05}Einstein, A. 1905. Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Köper.Germany.522 s.
\end{thebibliography}
```

and to get get rid of numbering `\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}` code

and for citation use `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` package and citation code is `\citep{Ein05}`, so result is (Einstein, 1905)