# Biblatex not shortening authorlist

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I am trying to let Latex shorten the authorlist in my bibliography automatically, but it seems to ignore my settings. 
This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, maxnames=2,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\begin{document}

This is testing text...
\cite{Huebler2011}
\cite{Pierre2015}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This gives me following result:

[image]

As you can see, the selected style is applied, but all authors appear in the bibliography list. I am using TeXnicCenter with MikTex 2.9.

I get one warning message after compilation, which reads `Package Biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend`. I did some online search on that too, as it seems related to the problem, but haven't found anything helpful. Not specifieing a backend does not generate a bibliography at all.

I hope this doesn't turn out to be a stupid newbie mistake, but could very well be. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The options should actually work. If the screen shot you show us comes from the exact MWE you posted, the problem might lie with the `.bib` file. You need to separate names with an `and` in the author list and not with a semicolon, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped. I thought I'd get noticed by my IDE if I mess up the separators and such. Can't upvote comments, but you Sir saved my day.

Comment: I'd expect BibTeX/Biber to complain about the name format, but I'm not sure what BibTeX actually has to say in these instances. And then it is still an issue of how your IDE reports these things if they are no errors that stop the document from compiling properly.

Comment: See also [How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864)