# How to make a complete list of authors from bibtex file using JabRef

Tags: texstudio, acronyms, jabref, author

I would like to make a complete list of authors of a bibtex file that contain more than 100 entries, independently of the entry to which they belong to. As I use Jabref, I wonder if there is a way to do it in the same software.

The idea behind this is to check that all the names are correctly spelled. In the database I have the same author ("Alex B. Surname") with different formats, for example, Surname A.B., Surname AB, Surname A, Alex Surname, etc.

If you know another way to standardise the author names, I would also appreciate your help.

The issue is the same than [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354293/normalize-authors-names-in-bib-file), but I do not work with python.
I use Ubuntu/Arch Linux, TexStudio and Jabref.

Thanks in advance!
Marcos

Comment: JabRef isn't a relational database, and I don't think it can help you with this. If you don't want to employ any other software, your best bet for validation may be to open every record in the bottom pane and run "get BibTex data from DOI" in the "General" tab. (If you don't have the DOI, run "Get DOI" first.) If JabRef finds the online version, then it will show you the old and the new side by side, and you can approve or reject changes.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer, thanks for your suggestion, but most of the entries come from the original journals or publishers. The original bibtex are wrongly produced, so I do not think using the doi will solve the problem. If there is not choice with JabRef, I would like to know if there is any alternative to the solution given by @sdaau, with Python and `bibtexparser` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354293/normalize-authors-names-in-bib-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Hi, JabRef has a formatter for author fields, which can be used with quality-Cleanup for all entries. To export the list I would suggest having a look at the custom export function. You can create your own export format, for example you can export to csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this. Make a copy of the .bib file and then open it in a text editor. I use Notepad++. Select all and then sort. Each field sorts its lines together so that the file becomes a set of lists, one for each field.

In another copy of the original .bib file I change whatever I want and save to a new name. Then Jabref opens it as a new database containing all my changes.

This is a lot faster than making corrections using the JabRef GUI. I can also email new .bib files to another JabRef user who is on a Mac using the platform independent version of JabRef.