# How to manually change sort and name format of reference list in latex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting, jabref, apacite

In my bibliography, I have an author named 'R de Jong'.

Using the apacite package, in my reference list the author is sorted under 'd' and is displayed as

```
de Jong, R. (year). article name etc.
```

However, as it concerns only one author, I would like to manually change this into

```
Jong, R. de (year). article name etc.
```

and sort this author under 'j'. How should I do that?

I am currently using Jabref for managing my references.

Comment: Please do not show us only some problems with the result of your document. To reproduce, analyze and solve such problems we need a [minimal but working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography). Without such an example, this question looks like an duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

similar as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557/how-should-i-type-author-names-in-a-bib-file), you should put a bracket around {J}, something like:

```
   @article{Jong,
   author = {de {J}ong, R.} ...
```

The bibtex entry is as follows

```
@Article{Jong,
  author  = {Jong, {\relax R. de}},
  title   = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {2017},
  volume  = {16},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {17-24},
}
```

Underneath a MWE of the tex file

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}

\nocite{*}
\setlength{\bibsep}{1pt}
\bibliography{refscriptie.bib}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still results in the format 'de Jong, R.'. I found however that author = {Jong, {\relax P. de}} results in 'Jong, R. de. (year). '. Now, only the dot after 'de' has to be removed. How should I do that?

Comment: @Esmee Could you give a MWE of both the .tex file and .bib file - because the output of bibliography also depends on the bibliography style and other options...

Comment: sorry, I added the MWE's to your post.

Comment: @Esmee You should not add an MWE to the answer of someone else. Please edit your question and add an [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) for your problem there.