# My .bib file always throws 3 errors. How to fix it?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

Whenever I run my file in the following manner:
      report.tex pdflatex
      report.tex bibtex
      report.texpdflatex x2
I get these errors:
    This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) The top-level 
    auxiliary 
    file: report.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file 
    report.aux 
    I found no \bibdata command---while reading file report.aux I found no 
    \bibstyle command---while reading file report.aux (There were 3 error 
    messages
My latex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
 \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
 \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
 \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{titlepage}
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
 \clearpage

 \title{\bfseries Neighbourhood Analysis of \\ Naive Sphere Points}
 \author{ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\\bfseries Tushar Chandra\\ \\
     Mentored By\\ \\
 \bfseries Dr. Ranita Biswas }
 \maketitle
 \end{titlepage}
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
 \clearpage
 \section*{}
 \begin{center}

 \huge{Department of Computer Science and Engineering}\\[0.5cm]
 \normalsize
 \textsc{Indian Institute of Technology Roorkee}\\[2.0cm]

 \emph{\LARGE Certificate}\\[2.5cm]
 \end{center}
 \normalsize This is to certify that, Tushar Chandra, student of B.Tech has 
  succesfully completed his summer research project on the topic \textit{ 
  Analysis of Naive Sphere Points} under my guidance.\\[1.0cm]
  \begin{flushright}
  \vfill
  Dr. Ranita Biswas\\
  Assistant Professor,\\
  Dept. of Comp. Sc.,\\
  IIT Roorkee\\
  \end{flushright}
  \begin{flushleft}
  Date:
 \end{flushleft} 
 \newpage         
 \pagenumbering{gobble}               
 \clearpage 

 \section{Main}
 We can see that number of voxels having 8-neighbours are the least and even 
 0 for many values of radius while number of voxels having 7-neighbours show 
 extreme decrease and increase in values. The spikes in no. of voxels having 
 6-neighbours keeps on increasing with increasing radius and the highest 
 peak in observed at radius=49.The highest peak for voxels having 7 
 neighbours and 8 neighbours are observed at radius=48.


\newpage
\section*{REFERENCE}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}

* bib file
  @PhdThesis{one,
  author    =   {Dr. Ranita Biswas},
  title     =   {On Discretization of Sphere and Related Problems in 3D 
  Integer Space(PhD Thesis)},
  school    =   {Indian Institute of Technology, Kharagpur},
  year      =   {2016},
  }
  @InCollection{two,
  author    =   {Ranita Biswas and Partha Bhowmick},
  title     =  {On the Functionality and Usefulness of Quadraginta Octants 
  of Naive Sphere},
  booktitle =   {Journal of Mathematical Imaging and Vision},
  year      =   {2017},
  publisher =   {Springer}
  }

  @Article{three,
  author    =   {Ranita Biswas, Partha Bhowmick and Valentin E. Brimkov},
  title     =   {On the Polyhedra of Graceful Spheres and Circular 
                 Geodesics},
  journal   =   {Discrete Applied Mathematics},
  volume    =   {216, Part 2},
  pages     =   {362--375},
  year      =    {2016},
  }
  @Article{four,
  author    =   {Ranita Biswas, Partha Bhowmick},
  title     =   {On different topological of spherical geodesic paths and 
  circles in Z^{3}},
  journal   =   {Theoretical Computer Science},
  volume    =   {605},
  pages     =   {146--163},
  year      =   {2015},
  }

  @Article{five,
  author    =   {Ranita Biswas and Partha Bhowmick},
  title     =   {From prima quadraginta octant to lattice sphere through 
                 primitive integer operations},
  journal   =   {Theoretical Computer Science},
  volume    =   {624},
  pages     =   {56--72},
  year      =   {2016},
  }

  @article{six,
  author    =   {Cohen-Or,D., Kaufman},
  title     =   {A.: Fundamentals of surface voxelization.},
  journal   =   {Graph. Models Image Process. },
  volume    =   {57(6)},
  pages     =   {453--461},
  year      =   {1995},
  }

  @Article{seven,
  author    =   {Klette, R., Rosenfeld},
  title     =   {A.: Digital Geometry: Geometric Methods for Digital Picture 
                 Analysis},
  journal   =   {Morgan Kaufmann, San Francisco},
  year      =   {2004},
  }
```

I have spent 4 hours looking on the net but nothing worked.

Comment: May I suggest a free ebook to you? http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html (please don't take the title as an insult :) it's well written and I think it contains a lot of useful information for you)

Answer (score 3):

> Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559/36296 many of the author names in your bib file are inserted incorrectly and thus appear seriously broken in the output -- for example Reinhard Klette and Azriel Rosenfeld are two people and not "R. A. Rosenfeld Klette". There are also other that are now fixed: articles are not `incollection` and books are not `article`, for instance. Some checks with Google Scholar were sufficient to find the right citations.

You cannot use `^{3}` outside of math mode; material that should not change capitalization should be braced. I also get errors from the combination of packages you use -- had to remove `algorithm` to make it compile.

### `mybib.bib` file

```
@PhdThesis{one,
  author    = {Ranita Biswas},
  title     = {On Discretization of Sphere and Related Problems in {3D} Integer Space},
  school    = {Indian Institute of Technology, Kharagpur},
  year      = {2016},
}
@article{two,
  author    = {Ranita Biswas and Partha Bhowmick},
  title     = {On the Functionality and Usefulness of Quadraginta Octants of Naive Sphere},
  journal   = {Journal of Mathematical Imaging and Vision},
  year      = {2017},
  pages     = {69-83},
  }

@Article{three,
  author    = {Ranita Biswas and Partha Bhowmick and Valentin E. Brimkov},
  title     = {On the Polyhedra of Graceful Spheres and Circular Geodesics},
  journal   = {Discrete Applied Mathematics},
  volume    = {216, Part 2},
  pages     = {362--375},
  year      = {2016},
}
@Article{four,
  author    = {Ranita Biswas and Partha Bhowmick},
  title     = {On different topological of spherical geodesic paths and circles in {$Z^{3}$}},
  journal   = {Theoretical Computer Science},
  volume    = {605},
  pages     = {146--163},
  year      = {2015},
}

@Article{five,
  author    = {Ranita Biswas and Partha Bhowmick},
  title     = {From prima quadraginta octant to lattice sphere through 
               primitive integer operations},
  journal   = {Theoretical Computer Science},
  volume    = {624},
  pages     = {56--72},
  year      = {2016},
}

@article{six,
  author    = {Cohen-Or, D. and Kaufman, A.},
  title     = {Fundamentals of surface voxelization},
  journal   = {Graphical Models and Image Processing},
  volume    = {57},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {453--461},
  year      = {1995},
}

@book{seven,
  author    = {Klette, R. and Rosenfeld, A.},
  title     = {Digital geometry: {Geometric} methods for digital picture analysis},
  year      = {2004},
  publisher = {Elsevier}
}
```

### `test.tex` file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
% \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62709/discussion-on-answer-by-samcarter-my-bib-file-always-throws-3-errors-how-to-fi).