# Biblatex not showing with biber + apa style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Biblatex not showing with biber + apa style...help me, please.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@BOOK{RonCal11th,
  author =       {{Ron Larson}{, Bruce Edwards}},
  title =        {Calculus},
  publisher =    {Cengage Learning},
  year =         {2018},
  edition =      {11th},
  keywords =     {english},
}

@BOOK{NBK2015,
  author =       {Nguyễn Bá Kim},
  title =        {Phương pháp dạy học môn Toán},
  publisher =    {Nhà xuất bản Đại học Sư Phạm},
  year =         {2015},
  keywords =     {vietnam},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,keyword={vietnam},title={Tiếng Việt}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,keyword={english},title={Tiếng Anh}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE won't give any output since you haven't cited anything! Try `\cite{NBK2015}`. If your real document has a `\cite` or `\nocite` in it, something else is going on. Do you get any errors or warnings in the `.log` file? What does the `.blg` file say? Did you run Biber?

Comment: How to run Biber in WinEdt 10?

Comment: Tada: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. But remember that you MWE will only produce citations (or in fact any output at all) once you add a `\cite` or `\nocite`.

Comment: Does that mean it works now? Would you say that your question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864?

Comment: Oh I forgot: `author =       {{Ron Larson}{, Bruce Edwards}},` is wrong, you want `author = {Ron Larson and Bruce Edwards},`. Note the `and` and lack of double bracing. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: For the WinEdt problem, the  `LaTeXify` configuration component can be installed You'll find it on this page of ). [WinEdt.org](http://www.winedt.org/config.html). Among other things, it adds a `biber` item with its own shortcut to the `TeX` menu and a dedicated icon in the toolbar.