# problems with article citing with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, article, books

I want to make a citing for the European Unions report on the "implementation of the Council: Recommendation on cancer screening".

```
@Article{IARC2017,
  author       = {Ponti A, Anttila A, Ronco G, Senore C, Basu P, Segnan N},
  title        = {Cancer screening in the European Union},
  journal      = {EU report: Against Cancer},
  year         = {2017},
  pages        = {20--28},
  publisher = {European Union},
 url     = {https://ec.europa.eu/health/sites/health/files/major_chronic_diseases/docs/2017_cancerscreening_2ndreportimplementation_en.pdf},
}
```

I get this error message: `Citation 'IARC2017' on page 3 undefined` .

I initially wanted to refer this as a report, but couldnt make it work even though i filled out every mandatory field. I then tried the article format, but this doesnt work either!! I have tried to remove everything that could possibly upset latex/biblatex, but i cannot understand what this is.. 
I also have problems with the "book" format with biblatex in general. It does not work on any references. For example this one:

```
@Book{Andrews1994,
  author      = {Andrews LB, Fullarton JE, Holtzman NA},
  title       = {Assessing Genetic Risks: Implications for Health and Social Policy},
  year        = {1994},
  editor      = {National Academies Press US},
  subtitle    = {Social, Legal, and Ethical Implications of Genetic Testing},
  publisher   = {National Academies Press US},
  isbn        = {0309047986},
  chapter     = {8},
  url         = {https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK236044/},
  pmid        = {25144102},
  publocation = {Washington DC},
  pubstatus   = {ppublish},
  pubtype     = {Review},
}
```

Can anyone see whats wrong? I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by 'it doesn't work'? Do you get warnings or errors? Is the output different from what you expected? What output did you expect, what did you get? Please note that the output depends on the bibliography and citation style you use as well, so we can only halp you properly if you show us a short example document that include information about those as well (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: That said `author = {Ponti A, Anttila A, Ronco G, Senore C, Basu P, Segnan N},` is wrong, it should `author = {Ponti, A. adn Anttila, A. and Ronco, G. and Senore, C. and Basu, P. and Segnan, N.},` and similarly for the authors of `Andrews1994`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: !!!! That did the trick. Thank you. I feel quite stupid, now it seems so obvious.. Thank you again.

Comment: But now that we have solved the issue, I believe that `IARC2017` is definitely not an `@article`. `@report` would probably work fine, but you could also try `@online`.

Comment: I changed it to the report format and that worked fine now. :)