# How to put 'and' between name of authors

Tags: citing, author

I am currently working on a paper and using overleaf online editor to write it. Problem is, that I am not able to put `and` between name of two authors and it is limited to those cases where the paper that I'm citing has only two authors and works for other cases. Here is a sample  bibtex:

```
@article{nikora2004water,
  title={Water-worked gravel surfaces: High-order structure functions at the particle scale},
  author={Nikora, Vladimir, and Walsh, Jeremy},
  journal={Water Resources Research},
  volume={40},
  number={12},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

I have tried following variations:

```
author={Nikora, Vladimir, and Walsh, Jeremy},
author={Nikora, Vladimir and, Walsh, Jeremy},
author={Nikora, Vladimir and Walsh, Jeremy},
author={Nikora, Vladimir and Walsh, Jeremy},
```

and none of them work. Here is the sample output of what happens:

[image]
[image]

My desired output is to see `V. Nikora and J. Walsh` and I am not able to get there. I have to mentioned that I've tried using `\usepackage{natbib}` which did not fix anything as well.

Comment: The comma should only separate the surname (last name) from the first name. So your last variation is the correct one. Did you delete your aux files and recompile?

Comment: But the output format of the names in your document assuming a correct `.bib` file is dependent on the bibliography style you use, in which case we'd need to see how you are creating the bibliography.  The format `A. Author and B. Author` is quite unusual. More usual would be `Author, A. and B. Author`.

Comment: From the examples `author={Nikora, Vladimir and Walsh, Jeremy},` is the only correct version. You must always separated all names in the name field with `and` and write a name as `First Last` or `Last, First` (or `von Last, Jr, First`). The name must not contain trailing commas (as in the incorrect `Nikora, Vladimir, and`) or starting commas (as in the incorrect `and, Walsh, Jeremy`). This is largely independent of the output you want to see in your document. The output is completely determined by your bibliography style. ...

Comment: ... So I suggest you use the correct form `author={Nikora, Vladimir and Walsh, Jeremy},` and then either switch or modify your bibliography style to give the output you want. If you need help with that you need to tell us which bibliography style you use, ideally in a short example document (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864