# Reference in IEEE style: BibTeX-key appears instead of numbers

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have saved some references in a library.bib file, using JabRef. One of these entries is the following:

```
@Article{Feng2014, 
    author = {Bo Feng, Mengyin Fu, Hongbin Ma, Yuanqing Xia, Bo Wang},
    title = {Kalman filter with recursive covariance estimatio - sequentially estimating process noise covariance}, 
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Industrial Electronics},
    year = {2014}, 
    volume = {61},
    number = {11},
    pages = {6253-6263}
}
```

Now I want to include citations in my TeX-document:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=ieee,sorting=none,dateabbrev=false,urldate=comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./library.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
Equations given in this section have been taken from \cite{Feng2014} and
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

I am running PDFLaTeX, Biber, PDFLaTex, PDFLaTeX. The references should be included as numbers, such as [1], wherever the citation is used. Instead of the number, however, the name of the BibTeX-key is given. And the reference is not included in the bibliography.

I have tried to make this a MWE. When I run this code now, the bibliography is not printed at all and the reference within the text is given as the BibTeX-key.

Comment: As always on this site: If you want other to help you then please post a full but minimal example. This is just a preamble (where a lot of stuff are irrelevant for your question). That way others can easily copy your example and test it out. As it sits now, we have to fill in several details, which often causes others on pass on a question like this.

Comment: @daleif: Ok, I have tried to make this an MWE now. I am using a customized template, so things are a little bit different for me. But the problem arises with this given example as well.

Comment: Are you sure the bib data is suppose to be provided like that? Doesn't biblatex normally use `\addbibresource`?

Comment: whops, you're right. This is how it is included in my document as well. But it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: The name format is wrong. Regardless of the desired output all names must be separated with `and` a comma may only be used to separate name parts as in *Family, Given* and *von Family, Jr., Given*. You probably want `author = {Bo Feng and Mengyin Fu and Hongbin Ma and Yuanqing Xia and Bo Wang},`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864

Comment: @moewe: that's it! ... interesting. This must be due to the ieee citation style, since the BibTeX-code I was using is the exact same found on Google scholar (so it should work e.g. for Harvard citation style). Thx so much!

Comment: No, it is *always* required to separate several authors with `and` in the BibTeX syntax regardless of the style you use. If Google scholar exports the entry like this it is simply wrong. BibTeX may be slightly more forgiving when processing an entry with a malformed name than Biber, but it is wrong in any case.

Comment: Mhh, just checked, for me Google Scholar exports `author={Feng, Bo and Fu, Mengyin and Ma, Hongbin and Xia, Yuanqing and Wang, Bo},`, which would be correct.

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem was solved with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864? In that case it may make sense to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @moewe: yes, i confirm!