# Why the second references author name become '-' when the author having 2 books but different title?

Tags: biblatex

```
@article{1testing,
  title={Title 1},
  author={Zanthony1, Anthony2 and Anthony3},
  journal={Journal 1},
  volume={24},
  number={2},
  pages={258--300},
  year={1992},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{2testing,
  title={Title 2},
  author={Zanthony1, Anthony2 and Anthony3},
  journal={Journal 2},
  volume={24},
  number={2},
  pages={200--264},
  year={1992},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

Both books by same author but different title of the book.

[image]

using:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
    \cite{1testing}     
    \cite{2testing}
```

Comment: That is the default with the `author-year` style, to avoid repetitions.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid repetitions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I would say ‘yes, replacing the name with a dash,, from the second occurrence’.

Comment: @Bernard, I want all the author name appear, do not use `-` in repetitions, how can I do that?

Comment: The option `[dashed=false]` should be enough.

Comment: @Bernard. thanks. it worked! `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear, dashed=false]{biblatex}`

Comment: Note that `style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear,` is  redundant, it is equivalent to the shorter and easier to parse `style=authoryear,`. Note also that `author={Zanthony1, Anthony2 and Anthony3},` is a list of *two* names, not three. All authors must be separated with `and`, commas are only used to separate parts of the same name, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864.

Comment: Since we discussed tagging under one of your questions recently: For this question `biblatex` would have been the appropriate tag, since your document loads the package and the question is specifically about output produced by `biblatex`. Note that `cross-referencing` is not the same as the generic `cite` or `bibliographies` tag. `cross-referencing` is about `\label` and `\ref`.

Comment: @moewe, thanks!