# Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed when adding new reference

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I took an existing framework that I used a couple of years ago in order to use it as a template for something I am writing currently. Many of the sources are still relevant, and so I left the bibliography the same. I tested it and made sure it worked, and then began making my changes. Everything was going fine until I attempted to add another reference into my bibliography - I used the exact same format as the rest of the references, but this time it caused TeXworks to fail to compile the document, spitting out the message:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
```

`The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:`

```
C:\Users\mattd\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log
```

Now, I went and checked that file, and it contained absolutely no helpful information, with it giving me the following block:

```
2020-02-11 14:38:44,408-0500 INFO  texify - starting with command line:
"D:\Users\mattd\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean Thesis.tex
2020-02-11 14:38:46,783-0500 FATAL texify - BibTeX failed for some reason.
2020-02-11 14:38:46,783-0500 FATAL texify - Info: 
2020-02-11 14:38:46,783-0500 FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
2020-02-11 14:38:46,783-0500 FATAL texify - Line: 1350
```

I've found a couple of things that other people have said, i.e. deleting the .aux, .bbl, and .toc files, which didn't help. I also tried running just pdfLaTeX, then just BibTex, and then just pdfLaTeX again to see what happens. pdfLaTeX runs just fine, but doesn't add any references to the document. When I try to run BibTex, I get the following message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: Thesis.aux
The style file: unsrt.bst
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 121 of file Thesis.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {unsrtnat}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: C:/Users/mattd/OneDrive/Documents/PocarLab/PhDResearch/MastersThesis/Bibliography.bib
Name 1 in "T.S. van Albada, J.N. Bahcall, K. Begeman, and R. Sanscisi" has a comma at the end for entry Reference31
while executing---line 944 of file unsrt.bst
Name 1 in "NASA, ESA, and J. Richard" has a comma at the end for entry Reference32
while executing---line 944 of file unsrt.bst
Warning--empty publisher in Reference32
Name 1 in "P. H. Frampton, M. Kawasaki, F. Takahashi, and T. T. Yanagida" has a comma at the end for entry Reference13
while executing---line 944 of file unsrt.bst
Name 1 in "D. Boyanovsky, H. J. de Vega, and D.J. Schwarz" has a comma at the end for entry Reference9
while executing---line 944 of file unsrt.bst
Name 1 in "B. J. Carr, K. Kohri, Y. Sendouda, and J. Yokoyama" has a comma at the end for entry Reference15
while executing---line 944 of file unsrt.bst
Name 1 in "A. Boyarski, O. Ruchayskiy, and M. Shaposhnikov" has a comma at the end for entry Reference20
while executing---line 944 of file unsrt.bst
Name 1 in "G. Jungman, M. Kamionkowski, and K. Griest" has a comma at the end for entry Reference21
while executing---line 944 of file unsrt.bst
Name 1 in "C. Savage, G. Gelmini, P. Gondolo, and K. Freese" has a comma at the end for entry Reference24
while executing---line 944 of file unsrt.bst
Name 1 in "J. Billard, E. Figueroa-Feliciano, and L. Strigari" has a comma at the end for entry Reference28
while executing---line 944 of file unsrt.bst
(There were 10 error messages)
```

Which also appears when I compile the document without the added reference, and it works absolutely fine without the added reference and so I continued on. Then I run pdfLaTeX again and once again it compiles, and this time it has the Table of Contents filled in but still no references in the text. If I try to run pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTeX it still fails to compile giving me the error from before. I can't figure it out for the life of me. In case it's important, the reference I'm trying to add is:

```
@article{Reference33,
    Author = {R.J. Noer},
    Journal = {Applied Physics A},
    Volume = 28,
    Title = {Electron field emission from broad-area electrodes},
    Pages = {1-24},
    Year = 1982
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. The first thing to do is to update MikTeX in both user and administrator mode.

Comment: The message `Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 121 of file Thesis.aux` suggests that your document contains two `\bibliographystyle` declarations. But you can only have one. (The second `\bibliographystyle` can be hiding in a different file if you use a badly coded template.) Make sure that you only have one `\bibliographystyle`. The other messages are all related to incorrectly formatted name fields: All names must be separated with an `and` in the input regardless of the expected output ...

Comment: e.g. it should be `author = {G. Jungman and M. Kamionkowski and K. Griest},` instead of the incorrect `author = {G. Jungman, M. Kamionkowski, and K. Griest},` See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864

Comment: Thank you! Deleting the `\bibliographystyle` from the file Thesis.aux fixed the issue. This feels weird to me since deleting the file outright didn't fix anything, but whatever works I guess!

Comment: In terms of the author names - using "and" creates a bibliography where the citations just have the names listed with no separators, so there are no commas or "and"s between each of the authors' names, which makes the citations look strange.

Comment: Mhhh, you shouldn't have to delete stuff from the `.aux`. The `.aux` is rewritten at every LaTeX run. Instead you should try to find out why you have two bibliography style definitions in your `.aux` and make sure that the document only has one `\bibliographystyle` directive. Re the `and`: The only correct way to input lists of names is with an `and`. If your bibliography style produces weird output in that case, then maybe you should look into using a different style. Using incorrect markup to force 'sensible' output can badly backfire.