# Omit prefix of authors surname in citation but not in bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I have the following bibliography setup

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bla.bib}
    @article{Leon1984,
        author  = "Frank {de León} and George Orwell",
        title   = "1984",
        year    = "1948",
        journal = "Books about big brothers",
        volume  = "5",
        number  = "42",
        pages   = "100--111"
    }
\end{filecontents}


\RequirePackage[backend=biber,
                style=ieee-alphabetic, % does not work with maxalphanames
                maxnames=99,
                minalphanames=1,
                maxcitenames=2,    
                maxalphanames=1,  
                firstinits=true,
                doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
                backref=false,
                dashed=false,
                defernumbers=true,
                ]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

% Label with full year
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field{year}    
  }
}

\addbibresource{bla.bib}
\begin{document}
    \cite{Leon1984}. \\
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

With the following output:

[image]

I am not happy how the surname of "Frank de León" is displayed. I'd like to have his name correctly in the bibliography, which I can achieve by braces like that: `Frank {de León}`. But I would like to omit the word "de" within the citation and only see **[León1984]**. Do you think it is possible?

As this is a very rare case, I would be happy with a non-general solution only for "de".

I experimented also with `useprefix` but I it has no effect at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BibTeX and Biber can deal with name prefixes like "de", "van", "von" etc. better if you drop the braces and give the name as

```
author  = {Frank de León and George Orwell},
```

or

```
author = {von Brandt, Ahasver},
```

See also [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864). If you write `Frank {de León}` then BibTeX and Biber parse the name as as being made up of given name "Frank" and family name "de León". Whereas with the input `Frank de León` they see given name "Frank", family name "León", prefix "de". With that it is much easier to treat the "de Leon" different from "Orwell".

With the right input it is just a matter of setting the option `useprefix=false,` to tell `biblatex` not to use the prefix for the citation label.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=ieee-alphabetic,
            maxnames=99,
            maxcitenames=2,
            minalphanames=1, maxalphanames=1,
            giveninits=true,
            useprefix=false,
            doi=false, isbn=false, url=false,
            backref=false,
            dashed=false,
            ]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}


\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field{year}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Leon1984,
  author  = {Frank de León and George Orwell},
  title   = {1984},
  year    = {1948},
  journal = {Books About Big Brothers},
  volume  = {5},
  number  = {42},
  pages   = {100--111},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\cite{Leon1984}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [León1948] F. de León und G. Orwell]

Comment: @AlanMunn No, moewe interpreted my question right. I'm sorry if it was not entirely clear. The labels should be the same in text and bibliography, but I don't want to drop the prefix in the actual reference, which happened with my own attempts

Comment: @thewaywewalk Ok, that's good, because it wouldn't be an ideal format otherwise. :)