# Names in Bibliography with Cyrillic not displayed

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel, unicode, apacite

I'm trying to include names of institutions written in Cyrillic in the bibliography list, with the following code:

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
    \cite{item:2020}

    \newpage
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{resources}
\end{document}
```

In the `resources.bib` file there the following:

```
@article{abstract:2020,
    author  = {И.Иванов, Национална Природоматематическа Гимназия, Софийски Университет "Св. Климент Охридски"},
    title   = {Заглавие},
    journal = {Име},
    year    = {1000},
    volume  = {1},
    number  = {1},
    pages   = {1-2},
}
```

Instead of the names of the institutions, i.e. Национална Природоматематическа Гимназия Софийски Университет "Св. Климент Охридски", I get the following:

[image]

### Question:

What am I doing wrong? 
Is there a way to correct it?

---

### Update:

The solution using `biblatex+biber` as suggested by @Bernard:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[stylename=apa, style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{aparesources.bib}

\begin{document}

   \parencite{abstract:2020}

   \newpage
   \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Produces the following error:

[image]

---

Software used: Overleaf

Compiler: pdfLaTeX

Comment: Did you try with `biblatex+biber`? biber understands utf8.

Comment: @Bernard I just tried, however, it throws an error "too many commas, skipping entry 'abstract:2020'". If I omit the institution names it prints the bibliography list correctly.

Comment: @Bernard I've updated the question.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: `author  = {И.Иванов, Национална Природоматематическа Гимназия, Софийски Университет "Св. Климент Охридски"},` has too many commas. Name fields like `author` have a special input format and only accept properly formatted input. In your case that would probably be `author = {И. Иванов}`. The rest does not appear to be a name and needs to go elsewhere (or can be dropped; it looks like the affiliation of the author, which is usually not listed in the bibliography).

Comment: @moewe Thank you for the response! In the specific case the two authors are performing an experiment on students from the listed school using finance from the listed university. That is why the institutions are listed. You are probably right, they should be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name fields like `author` expect names as input and they expect them to be formatted according to the rules explained in [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864).

In your case that means that names should *not* include the academic affiliation of the author. The correct input for your entry would be

```
author  = {И. Иванов},
```

or

```
author  = {Иванов, И.},
```

Multiple authors would be separated with `and`

```
author  = {Иванов, И. and А. Антонов},
author  = {И. Иванов and А. Антонов and Фёдор Достоевский},
```

It is uncommon to include the academic affiliation in the bibliography, so I suggest you just drop the `Национална Природоматематическа Гимназия, Софийски Университет "Св. Климент Охридски"` bit.

`biblatex` is not compatible with

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

so I changed that to

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

But note that since April 2018 `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` has been the LaTeX default, so it need not be given at all. For full Unicode support (especially with fonts) you should be looking into LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX in which case both `inputenc` and `fontenc` should be dropped.

Note that `biblatex` knows no argument `stylename`, so `stylename=apa,` will throw an error, so I removed it. If you need APA style, load `biblatex` with `style=apa,` (7th. edition APA style) or `style=apa6,` (6th. edition APA style) [assuming an up-to-date distribution].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abstract:2020,
  author  = {И. Иванов},
  title   = {Заглавие},
  journal = {Име},
  year    = {1000},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1-2},
} 
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \parencite{abstract:2020}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Иванов, И. (1000). “Заглавие”. в: Име 1.1, с. 1—2.]