# Is there a way to sort the bibliography alphabetically?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am new in latex. My problem is the bibliographer is not ordered alphabetically. Is there a way to sort the bibliography alphabetically?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber, % bibtex  % bibtex or biber (prefered)
  natbib=true,
  style=alphabetic,
  sorting=none  % none, nty % no sorting or standard sorting
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliogra.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Bal89}, Balder E.J. \cite{DeB86} De Blasi F.S. and  Myjai J \cite{Dil93}, Dilworth S.J., Girardi M.; \cite{Gue97}, Guessous M. \cite{Kru00}, author=Krupa G.,\cite{Bal90}, author is Balder E.J., \cite{Kom67}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

bibliography

```
 @article{Bal89,
   author={Balder E.J.},
   title={Infinite-Dimentional Extention of a Theorem of Komlós},
   journal={Probability Theory and Related Fields},
   volume={81},
   year=1989,
   pages={185-188}
}
@article{DeB86,
   author={De Blasi F.S. and  Myjai J.},
   title={Weak convergence of convex sets in Banach spaces},
   journal={Archiv der Mathematik},
   volume={47},
   year=1986,
   pages={448-456}
}
@article{Dil93,
   author={Dilworth S.J., Girardi M.},
   title={Bochner vs. Pettis norm: examples and results},
   journal={Contemporary Mathematics},
   volume={144},
   year=1993,
   pages={69-80}
}
@article{Gue97,
   author={Guessous M.},
   title={An elementary proof of Komlós-Révész theorem in Hilbert spaces},
   journal={Convex Analysis},
   volume={4},
   year=1997,
   pages={321-332}
}
@article{Kru00,
   author={Krupa G.},
   title={Komlós Theorem for Unbounded Random Sets},
   journal={Set-Valued Analysis},
   volume={8},
   year=2000,
   pages={237–251}
}
@article{Bal90,
   author={Balder E.J.},
   title={New Sequential Compactness Results for Spaces of Scalarly Integrable Functions},
   journal={Mathematical Analysis ans Applications},
   volume={151},
   year=1990,
   pages={1-16}
}
@article{Kom67,
   author={Komlós J.},
   title={A generalization of a problem of Steinhaus},
   journal={Acta Mathematica Hungarica},
   volume={18},
   year=1967,
   pages={217–229}
}
```

the result :

[image]

Comment: Your names are not input correctly. `Family G. I.` is not a valid format, if you use the reversed format, you need a comma `Family, G. I.`. You also *must* separate multiple names with `and` regardless of the desired output: *`author={Dilworth S.J., Girardi M.},` is wrong, it should be `author={Dilworth, S.J. and Girardi, M.},`. `author={Komlós J.},` should be `author={Komlós, J.},` etc.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Comment: @moewe Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

The names are not input correctly. `Family G. I.` is not a valid format. If you use the reversed format, you need a comma

```
Family, G. I.
```

the other accepted format here would be the natural order

```
G. I. Family
```

Which method you choose does not matter for the output – as long as it is correct input.

So

*`author={Komlós J.},` should be

```
author={Komlós, J.},
```

You also *must* separate multiple names with `and` regardless of the desired output: *`author={Dilworth S.J., Girardi M.},` is wrong, it should be

```
author={Dilworth, S.J. and Girardi, M.},
```

See also [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864) and [How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864).

Note that `sorting=none,` will give you sorting by citation order. You probably don't want that with `style=alphabetic`. That style already chooses a sensible sorting (`sorting=anyt`), so you can just say

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  natbib=true,
  style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bal89,
  author  = {Balder, E.J.},
  title   = {Infinite-Dimentional Extention of a Theorem of {Komlós}},
  journal = {Probability Theory and Related Fields},
  volume  = {81},
  year    = 1989,
  pages   = {185-188},
}
@article{DeB86,
  author  = {De Blasi, F.S. and  Myjai, J.},  
  title   = {Weak convergence of convex sets in {Banach} spaces},
  journal = {Archiv der Mathematik},
  volume  = {47},
  year    = 1986,
  pages   = {448-456},
}
@article{Dil93,
  author  = {Dilworth, S.J. and Girardi, M.},
  title   = {{Bochner} vs. {Pettis} norm: examples and results},
  journal = {Contemporary Mathematics},
  volume  = {144},
  year    = 1993,
  pages   = {69-80},
}
@article{Gue97,
  author  = {Guessous, M.},
  title   = {An elementary proof of {Komlós-Révész} theorem in {Hilbert} spaces},
  journal = {Convex Analysis},
  volume  = {4},
  year    = 1997,
  pages   = {321-332},
}
@article{Kru00,
  author  = {Krupa, G.},
  title   = {{Komlós} Theorem for Unbounded Random Sets},
  journal = {Set-Valued Analysis},
  volume  = {8},
  year    = 2000,
  pages   = {237–251},
}
@article{Bal90,
  author  = {Balder, E.J.},
  title   = {New Sequential Compactness Results for Spaces of Scalarly Integrable Functions},
  journal = {Mathematical Analysis ans Applications},
  volume  = {151},
  year    = 1990,
  pages   = {1-16},
}
@article{Kom67,
  author  = {Komlós, J.},
  title   = {A generalization of a problem of {Steinhaus}},
  journal = {Acta Mathematica Hungarica},
  volume  = {18},
  year    = 1967,
  pages   = {217–229},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{Bal89,DeB86,Dil93,Gue97,Kru00,Bal90,Kom67}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Bal89] E.J. Balder. “Infinite-Dimentional Extention of a Theorem of Komlós”. In: Probability Theory and Related Fields 81 (1989), pp. 185–188.]