# Some of my references don't work even though they are spelled correctly and in the .bib-file

Tags: citing

[image: The references show up in this format when they dont work. I have not found any differences between the references that work and those that dont.]

My document is the report class and I only have this issue in one of my subsections. This is an example of a reference that does not work:

```
    @article{Wang2007,
      author  = {Wang, J. J., Sanderson, B. J., & Wang, H.},
      journal = {Mutation research},
      title   = {Cyto- and genotoxicity of ultrafine TiO2 particles in cultured human lymphoblastoid 
      cells},
      year    = {2007},
      number  = {2},
      pages   = {99–106},
      volume  = {628},
      doi     = {10.1016/j.mrgentox.2006.12.003},
    }
```

This is an example of a reference that does work in the same subsection:

```
    @Article{Fartkhooni2016,
      author   = {Fatemeh Mohammadi Fartkhooni; Ali Noori; Abdolrasool Mohammadi},
      journal  = {International Journal of Life Sciences},
      title    = {Effects of Titanium Dioxide Nanoparticles Toxicity on the Kidney of Male Rats},
      year     = {2016},
      number   = {1},
      pages    = {65-69},
      volume   = {10},
      doi      = {https://doi.org/10.3126/ijls.v10i1.14513},
      keywords = {Nano-TiO2, Kidney tissue, Renal factors, Toxicity},
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this can be answered using the information provided. Please edit your question and add a short LaTeX code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Both entries shown in the question have a malformed `author` field. Regardless of the desired output, multiple names *must* be separated with `and` in the input. Too many commas as in `Wang2007` can break entry parsing and may prevent it from resolving correctly. In `Fartkhooni2016` there are no commas that break parsing, but the output is still not going to be correct. `Wang2007`'s authors should be `author  = {Wang, J. J. and Sanderson, B. J. and Wang, H.},`. `Fartkhooni2016` should have `author = {Fatemeh Mohammadi Fartkhooni and Ali Noori and Abdolrasool Mohammadi},`

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864