# Reference vanishes when number of authors are more than 4

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

What could be the problem with following bibliography code? Problem is occurring when I try to add more than 4 authors, reference get added till 4 authors, if 5 or more authors, that reference does not appear.

For below entry I am getting reference printed in bibliography.

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=nyt,
citestyle=authoryear,
maxbibnames=99, 
maxcitenames=2,
]{biblatex}
@ARTICLE{a5,  author={L.  {Barrett, R. Adolphs} and S. {Pollak}},  journal={Association for Psychological Science},   title={Corrigendum: Emotional Expressions
Reconsidered: Challenges to Inferring
Emotion From Human Facial Movements}, year={2019},pages={1-50}}


[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

But when I add remaining authors like below, it does not get added to bibliography list

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=nyt,
citestyle=authoryear,
maxbibnames=99, 
maxcitenames=2,
]{biblatex}
@ARTICLE{a5,  author={L.  {Barrett, R. Adolphs, S. Marsella, M. Martinez} and S. {Pollak}},  journal={Association for Psychological Science},   title={Corrigendum: Emotional Expressions
Reconsidered: Challenges to Inferring
Emotion From Human Facial Movements}, year={2019},pages={1-50}}
```

Comment: Both `author={L.  {Barrett, R. Adolphs} and S. {Pollak}}` and `author={L.  {Barrett, R. Adolphs, S. Marsella, M. Martinez} and S. {Pollak}}, ` look wrong. All names must be separated with an `and` in the `author` field. I guess you want something like `author = {L. Barrett and R. Adolphs and S. Marsella and M. Martinez and S. Pollak},`. Each name (string between two `and`s can only contain two commas, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864, more commas will cause errors.) See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864

Answer (score 1):

According to BibTeX syntax, which is also used by Biber, in both examples the article has two authors, the first of which has a very peculiar name: in the first case it is

> L. (initial of given name) {Barrett, R. Adolphs} (family name)

and in the second case it is

> L. (initial of given name)  {Barrett, R. Adolphs, S. Marsella, M. Martinez} (family name)

The correct syntax would be, in the two cases

```
author={L. Barrett and S. Pollak},
author={L. Barrett and R. Adolphs and S. Marsella and M. Martinez and S. Pollak},
```