# Print author same format - biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have using `biblatex` package and would like to print author content in the same format. In the `bib` database `Yedidia J S and Freeman W T and Weiss Y` and would like to print in PDF same as `Yedidia J S and Freeman W T and Weiss Y`. And also how to add `ed` before `Lakemeyer`?(editor)

My MWE IS:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel,hyperref,fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes,microtype}
\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric,sorting=none,maxbibnames=5]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibnamedelimi}{\addnbspace}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{chapter}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inproceedings]{series}{(#1)}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{eid}{(#1)}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{note}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inproceedings,thesis,online]{title}{{#1}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{
\ifentrytype{article}{}{
\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{booktitle}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{{#1}}

\DeclareListFormat{location}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  (#1:\isdot
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\DeclareListFormat{publisher}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  #1\isdot)
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{publisher}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{location}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\entrysetpunct}{\par}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \let\finalandcomma\empty
  \let\finalandsemicolon\empty
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{series}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{journaltitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pages}%
  \finentry}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printnames{editor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{url}%
  \finentry}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printnames{editor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \finentry}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printnames{editor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pages}%
  \finentry}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ipab730bbib5,
 author ={Yedidia J S and Freeman W T and Weiss Y},
 year ={2003},
 title ={Exploring Artificial Intelligence in the New Millennium},
 editor={G Lakemeyer and B Nebel},
 location={San Francisco, CA},
 publisher={Morgan Kaufmann},
 pages={239},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid

```
author = {Yedidia J S and Freeman W T and Weiss Y},
```

is simply not supported input (at least assuming that *Yedidia*, *Freeman* and *Weiss* are the family names and *J. S.*, *W. T.* and *Y.* the given name initials of the authors).

The input BibTeX and Biber accept for names is explained in [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864).

One correct way to input the names would be

```
author = {Yedidia, J. S. and Freeman, W. T. and Weiss, Y.},
```

an alternative would be

```
author = {J. S. Yedidia and W. T. Freeman and Y. Weiss},
```

---

If the names are input correctly, you can use `biblatex` to have the names formatted however you wish.

You basically already have all the ingredients together for that (as shown in the following minimised code example)

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, maxbibnames=5, giveninits]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibnamedelimi}{\addnbspace}

% really?
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \let\finalandcomma\empty
  \let\finalandsemicolon\empty
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ipab730bbib5,
 author    = {Yedidia, J. S. and Freeman, W. T. and Weiss, Y.},
 year      = {2003},
 title     = {Exploring Artificial Intelligence in the New Millennium},
 editor    = {G. Lakemeyer and B. Nebel},
 location  = {San Francisco, CA},
 publisher = {Morgan Kaufmann},
 pagetotal = {239},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{ipab730bbib5}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Yedidia J S and Freeman W T and Weiss Y. Exploring Artificial Intelligence in the New Millennium. Ed. by Lakemeyer G and Nebel B. San Francisco, CA: Morgan Kaufmann, 2003. 239 pp.]

Note that here the editor is marked up as an editor.

In your code there is no "ed.", because your bibliography drivers just have

```
\printnames{editor}%
```

instead of something like

```
\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
```

which would also print the "ed." and much more.

If you compare your bibliography drivers to the standard definitions in [`standard.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx), you will find that the standard drivers make use of many more high-level bibmacros. If you don't use those you may lose out on some things.