# Should author field in bib files be in "First Last" format or "Last, First" format?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, author, portability

Is there a preferred way of writing the author name in `.bib` files between the two formats below?

```
@book{tgt,
  title = {The Great Title},
  author = {Jane Doe and Ron Wonder},
  year = {2022},
  publisher = {Macmillan},
  address = {Paris},
}
```

vs.

```
@book{tgt,
  title = {The Great Title},
  author = {Doe, Jane and Wonder, Ron},
  year = {2022},
  publisher = {Macmillan},
  address = {Paris},
}
```

I use `biblatex` and `biber` myself but I cannot always predict what tooling a journal I am submitting to is going to support. So I would like to choose a format that is portable enough and stick with it.

As I build my repository of bib entries, I want to make sure that all the effort I put into creating this "database" of references does not end up giving me trouble later because I chose a format that is incompatible with most journals out there.

Comment: I don't think Jane Doe cares about this, but Jane Smith Doe should be entered as `Smith Doe, Jane`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you input

```
author={Carl Philipp Emanuel Bach},
```

or

```
author{Bach, Carl Philipp Emanuel},
```

it's exactly the same. But

```
author={Jakob Ludwig Felix Mendelssohn Bartholdy},
```

and

```
author={Mendelssohn Bartholdy, Jakob Ludwig Felix},
```

are not the same: the former is wrong and the latter is good. Why is the former wrong? Because it would consider only “Bartholdy” as “last name”.

In the case of CPE Bach, the first three parts are “first name”.

As a general advice, the format “Last, First” is to be preferred, because it's less ambiguous. For simple names such as Abigail Uthor, it's not so important, but better to stick with the same format throughout the `.bib` file.

Other parts such as “von” and “jr” are often cause of headaches.

Comment: And then there are truly special names, such as "Ludwig Mies van der Rohe": the person has one given name (Ludwig) and one surname (Mies van der Rohe). :-) Definitely a must to write `author = {Mies van der Rohe, Ludwig}`...

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, https://www.bibtex.com/f/author-field/ states:

> BibTeX divides a person's name into four parts:
>
> - First: First names or given names
> - Last: Last name or family name
> - von: a particle (e.g., de, de la, der, van, von)
> - jr: a suffix (e.g., Jr., Sr., III)
>
> BibTeX's internal name parser knows three ways these name parts can be combined:
>
> - Method 1: First von Last
> - Method 2: von Last, First
> - Method 3: von Last, Jr, First

So either `Jane Doe` or `Doe, Jane` is fine.  In the `.bib` entries it won't matter; they don't determine the output you get when you process your file.  Ultimately, the output style you choose will determine whether to print out the name one way or the other (and may even reduce the first name to just an initial for some styles).

Comment: Thank you! So "First Last" and "Last, First" behave the same. That's great. Likewise "First von Last" and "von Last, First" behave the same. That's nice too. But "von Last, Jr, First" cannot be written as "First von Last Jr". That's a bummer! So anytime a suffix is involved it becomes necessary to switch to the comma separated name format?

Comment: So it would seem.

Comment: It's important to point out that the website bibtex.com and its purported owner, "Paperpile" [?],  have no known official connection to the creator of the BibTeX, *viz.*, Oren Patashnik, or to any other recognized BibTeX authorities.  Moreover, the advice given on bibtex.com is often either incomplete or downright erroneous. As such, I'd be reluctant to quote anything that's stated on the site unless I can double-check and verify the information for myself.

Comment: I offer the info I found in the "for what it's worth" category.  Feel free to suggest an edit or find another source that carries greater authority.

Comment: I think that inserting an explicit "for what it's worth" disclaimer when quoting anything from bibtex.com would be helpful for future readers of your answer.