# "Jane Smith Doe" vs. "Smith Doe, Jane" in author field of .bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, author

I have a `foo.tex` file like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}
\begin{document}
Some text \parencite{tgt}. Also see \textcite{tgt}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My `foo.bib` goes like this:

```
@book{tgt,
  title = {The Great Title},
  author = {Jane Smith Doe},
  year = {2022},
  publisher = {Macmillan},
  address = {Paris},
}
```

The output looks like this:

> Some text (Doe, 2022). Also see Doe (2022).
>
> #### References
>
> Doe, Jane Smith (2022). The Great Title. Paris: Macmillan.

Everything looks good so far. But then in the comment section of [Should author field in bib files be in "First Last" format or "Last, First" format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/672128/18587) I received this advice:

> I don't think Jane Doe cares about this, but Jane Smith Doe should be entered as `Smith Doe, Jane`.

This advice got a few upvotes too. So I tried this but it seems to give the wrong output. Modified bib file:

```
@book{tgt,
  title = {The Great Title},
  author = {Smith Doe, Jane},
  year = {2022},
  publisher = {Macmillan},
  address = {Paris},
}
```

Output:

> Some text (Smith Doe, 2022). Also see Smith Doe (2022).
>
> #### References
>
> Smith Doe, Jane (2022). The Great Title. Paris: Macmillan.

This output looks very wrong. "Smith Doe" has been picked up as last name whereas most citation styles require "Doe" to be picked up as the last name.

So my question is should we really write `Jane Smith Doe` as `Smith Doe, Jane` instead? Why? Am I implementing this advice wrong to get "Smith Doe" as the last name when "Doe" is desired?

Comment: If “Smith Doe” is the last name, why should “Doe” be used?

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your comment! I guess I am confused due to my unfamiliarity with English surnames. Is "Smith Doe" a popular last name? I thought "Smith" is the middle name and "Doe" is the last name. If the name was "Jane Smith-Doe" then I would have said "Smith-Doe" is the last name. But I could be wrong because I am not very familiar with such names. So please correct me if you think I am wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no rule. Not to mention Portuguese/Brazilian names: the very last one is the main one, usually; it's the reverse for Spanish.

Comment: You are not getting the advice wrong - if the last name is "Smith Doe", then the first cite is wrong (and the second correct). If Jane Doe has a middle name of Smith (and a last name of Doe), then the first cite is correct. In this specific case, "Smith" is an unusual middle name,  although I won't say it can't possibly be one. I'm fairly certain, however, that bibtex does not know of every form of "last name with a space in it" (e.g. 'Bon Jovi'), even if it knows some. Using "Last, First" gives bibtex information that 'just take the part after the last space' isn't right in a given case.

Comment: You wrote, *This output looks very wrong. "Smith Doe" has been picked up as last name whereas most citation styles require "Doe" to be picked up as the last name.* Please clarify what you mean by "most citation styles". For sure, I can't think of a single authoritative reference that requires the use of a single word -- "Doe", say -- if the author's surname consists of two words -- "Smith Doe", say.

Comment: @Mico I was not familiar with "Smith Doe" being a surname. I was mistaken that "Smith" can only be a middle name. But now from the comments it is clear that "Smith Doe" can be a surname and the second example would be correct for that.