# Biblatex references being ordered randomly

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I'm new to this whole latex thing and I'm having trouble understanding and defining the order in which my references appear after being compiled. I would like them to be sorted alphabetically based on the first entry in the "author" field; however, the order in which they are appearing in the PDF seems to be entirely random. What am I doing wrong?

Here's how a section of my .bib file is written as of right now:

```
@online{plano_diretor,
    author = "Belo Horizonte",
    title = " Lei nº 11.181, de 8 de agosto de 2019, aprova o Plano Diretor, em consonância com o disposto no Estatuto da Cidade",
    url  = "https://www.cmbh.mg.gov.br/atividade-legislativa/pesquisar-legislacao/lei/11181/2019",
    addendum = "(acesso em: 02/09/2023)",
    keywords = "plano_diretor,11.181"
}

@online{bh_map,
    author = "Prefeitura de Belo Horizonte",
    title = " BH Map - Mapa Oficial da Prefeitura de Belo Horizonte",
    url  = "https://bhmap.pbh.gov.br/v2/mapa/idebhgeo#zoom=4&lat=7796893.0925&lon=609250.9075&baselayer=base",
    addendum = "(acesso em: 02/09/2023)",
    keywords = "BH_Map,bh map"
}

@online{PMSBH,
    author = "Prefeitura de Belo Horizonte",
    title = "Plano Municipal de Saneamento de Belo
    Horizonte 2020/2023 (PMS 2020/2023).",
    url  = "https://prefeitura.pbh.gov.br/sites/default/files/estrutura-de-governo/obras-e-infraestrutura/2021/_pms2020-2023_texto_completo.pdf",
    addendum = "(acesso em: 02/09/2023)",
    keywords = "pmsbh"
}

@article{starling2015risco,
  title={O risco geol{\'o}gico como justificativa para remo{\c{c}}{\~o}es for{\c{c}}a-\\das no Aglomerado Santa L{\'u}cia e na Vila Bandeirantes em Belo Horizonte},
  author={Starling, Paula Miller},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Universidade Federal de Minas Gerais}
}

@article{PRAD_ICMbio,
  title={Roteiro de Apresentação para Plano de Recuperação
de Área Degradada (PRAD) Terrestre},
  author={Instituto Chico Mendes da Conservação da Biodiversidade - ICMbio},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Ministério do Meio Ambiente}
}

@article{Unidades_Geotecnicas,
  title={Caracterização das unidades geotécnicas da porção leste da região metropolitana de Belo Horizonte–MG},
  author={dos Reis Junior, Walter and Parizzi, Maria Giovana},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Geonomos}
}

@article{areas_inundacao,
  title={Áreas de risco município de Belo Horizonte},
  author={PRODABEL},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Prefeitura de Belo Horizonte}
}

@article{NBR12216,
  title={NBR 12216: Projeto de estação de tratamento de água para abastecimento público},
  author={Associação Brasileira de Normas Técnicas},
  year={1992},
  publisher={ABNT}
}

@article{Abastecimento_agua,
  title={Abastecimento de Água para Consumo Humano},
  author={Heller, Léo and de Pádua, Valter Lúcio},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Editora UFMG}
}
```

here's how my main.tex file looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=nyt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\input{00_config}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


\belowcaptionskip=10pt

\newtoggle{beforesection}
\preto\section{\toggletrue{beforesection}}
\preto\subsection{\toggletrue{beforesection}}
\preto\subsubsection{\toggletrue{beforesection}}
\preto\table{\iftoggle{beforesection}{\togglefalse{beforesection}}{}}

\newtoggle{captionedtable}
\preto\caption{\toggletrue{captionedtable}}
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\iftoggle{beforesection}{\iftoggle{captionedtable}{\togglefalse{captionedtable}}{\vspace{-30pt}}}{\iftoggle{captionedtable}{\togglefalse{captionedtable}}{\vspace{-15pt}}}}

\AtEndEnvironment{figure}{{\vspace{-10pt}}}

%começa cada seção em uma nova pagina
%\let\oldsection\section
%\renewcommand\section{\clearpage\oldsection}

\begin{document}


\input{titlepage}

\clearpage
\newpage
\input{folharosto}

\clearpage
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\clearpage
\newpage

\input{01_intro}
\input{02_objetivos}
\input{03_diag_area}
%\input{04_sistema_de_transportes}
\input{05_abastecimento_de_agua}
\input{06_esgotamento_sanitário}
\input{07_drenagem_de_águas_pluviais}
\input{08_aterro_sanitario}
\input{09_projeto_estrutural}
%\input{10_Conclusão}

\clearpage
\newpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\clearpage
\newpage

\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

and i will attach an image to show how my compiled file looks like

I wanted my references with authors whose names start with the letter "A" to appear first and so on.

I am definitely not a programmer and I am writing this document with five other colleagues, none of whom are programmers either, so I apologize for this messy code.

[image: compiled file]

Comment: We don't have the files you are `\input`ting, so we cannot run your example or even be sure that we see all the code we need to see to diagnose the problem. From what I can tell from the code so far you are missing curly braces around "corporate" authors (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864): It needs to be `author = "{Prefeitura de Belo Horizonte}",`, not `author = "Prefeitura de Belo Horizonte",`, otherwise Biber tries to split the name into family and given name and sort it that way, which goes wrong for non-person names. ...

Comment: ... Your screenshot shows more weird things, though, that the `.bib` file you have shown does not explain. Some names are separated with `e`, some with `&`. This shouldn't happen and I can only presume this is because you used the wrong input format. The correct format is explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864. It looks like you're trying to manually imitate ABNT style, in which case you should probably just load https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-abnt instead.

Comment: Thank you, Moewe, for your time. I managed to resolve all my issues by combining your advice with Andrew Swann's. I added the missing curly braces, loaded biblatex-abnt and added a sortkey where needded, as you suggested, and it worked like a charm after a few tweaks in the body of my document. I really appreciate your help, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bibliography is sorted according to the rule you passed to `biblatex`, namely `sorting=nyt`: so first by name of the author (last name, then first names), then by year and finally by title.  You should look at the [biblatex documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) for a description of other possible sorting options.  I would also recommend reading the section on the `author` field in the chapter 3 of the document ["Tame the beast"](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast), which carefully describes the required format.

However, in your case you also have different types of authors: some are people others are institutions.
As moewe said the institution names need to entered in the `.bib` file with extra enclosing braces

```
author = "{Prefeitura de Belo Horizonte}",
```

You can also optionally add a `sortkey`, for example if you wished the entry to be sorted as `Belo Horizonte`:

```
sortkey = {Belo Horizonte}
```

This gives

[image: Sample output]

for the input files, where I have specified the portuguese language option.

tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=nyt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

biblio.bib

```
@Online{plano_diretor,
  author =   {{Belo Horizonte}},
  title =    {Lei nº 11.181, de 8 de agosto de 2019, aprova o
                  Plano Diretor, em consonância com o disposto no
                  Estatuto da Cidade},
  url =
                  {https://www.cmbh.mg.gov.br/atividade-legislativa/pesquisar-legislacao/lei/11181/2019},
  addendum =     {(acesso em: 02/09/2023)},
  keywords =     {plano_diretor,11.181}
}

@Online{bh_map,
  author =   {{Prefeitura de Belo Horizonte}},
  title =    {BH Map - Mapa Oficial da Prefeitura de Belo
                  Horizonte},
  url =
                  {https://bhmap.pbh.gov.br/v2/mapa/idebhgeo#zoom=4&lat=7796893.0925&lon=609250.9075&baselayer=base},
  addendum =     {(acesso em: 02/09/2023)},
  sortkey =  {Belo Horizonte},
  keywords =     {BH_Map,bh map}
}

@Online{PMSBH,
  author =   {{Prefeitura de Belo Horizonte}},
  title =    {Plano Municipal de Saneamento de Belo Horizonte
                  2020/2023 (PMS 2020/2023).},
  url =
                  {https://prefeitura.pbh.gov.br/sites/default/files/estrutura-de-governo/obras-e-infraestrutura/2021/_pms2020-2023_texto_completo.pdf},
  addendum =     {(acesso em: 02/09/2023)},
  sortkey =  {Belo Horizonte},
  keywords =     {pmsbh}
}

@Article{starling2015risco,
  author =   {Starling, Paula Miller},
  title =    {O risco geol{\'o}gico como justificativa para
                  remo{\c{c}}{\~o}es for{\c{c}}adas no Aglomerado
                  Santa L{\'u}cia e na Vila Bandeirantes em Belo
                  Horizonte},
  year =     2015,
  publisher =    {Universidade Federal de Minas Gerais}
}

@Article{PRAD_ICMbio,
  author =   {{Instituto Chico Mendes da Conservação da
                  Biodiversidade - ICMbio}},
  title =    {Roteiro de Apresentação para Plano de Recuperação de
                  Área Degradada (PRAD) Terrestre},
  year =     2013,
  publisher =    {Ministério do Meio Ambiente}
}

@Article{Unidades_Geotecnicas,
  author =   {dos Reis Junior, Walter and Parizzi, Maria Giovana},
  title =    {Caracterização das unidades geotécnicas da porção
                  leste da região metropolitana de Belo Horizonte–MG},
  year =     2018,
  publisher =    {Geonomos}
}

@Article{areas_inundacao,
  author =   {{PRODABEL}},
  title =    {Áreas de risco município de Belo Horizonte},
  year =     2022,
  publisher =    {Prefeitura de Belo Horizonte}
}

@Article{NBR12216,
  author =   {{Associação Brasileira de Normas Técnicas}},
  title =    {NBR 12216: Projeto de estação de tratamento de água
                  para abastecimento público},
  year =     1992,
  publisher =    {ABNT}
}

@Article{Abastecimento_agua,
  author =   {Heller, Léo and de Pádua, Valter Lúcio},
  title =    {Abastecimento de Água para Consumo Humano},
  year =     2006,
  publisher =    {Editora UFMG}
}
```